# quick asp.net razor html helper

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, helper, mv

I have this:

```
<textarea name="body" rows="10" cols="80">@Model.Body</textarea><br />
```

Since I do not want a user to input javascript or html into the post for security reasons, I know that the html helpers eliminate that threat.

This is what I made so far:

I do not know where to put the @Model.Body so it renders as above.

```
@Html.TextArea("Message", new { rows = 10, columns = 80})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html.TextAreaFor in asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893171/html-textareafor-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: You should accept the duplicate then, since that answered your question.

Comment: Okay, I will do that. Sorry still new to the site.

Comment: I would gladly do that. Where is the button to do so? sorry still new to this site.

Comment: Sorry, not entirely sure. It's a new feature. I believe when I flagged the question as a duplicate it should have shown some sort of message. If you missed it or don't see it, then just ignore it.