# Bootstrap TextArea is NOT re-sizable in IE11

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-11

I'm implementing a MVC web application in ASP.NET.

Generating the View, gives me

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bio, 
                         new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }
)
```

I want to have TextArea so I changed it to

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Bio, 
                  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }
)
```

The problem is the text area is no resizable in IE11.
There is not issue on Chrome, FireFox and Opera.

I also have tried solution: [This Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893171/html-textareafor-in-asp-net-mvc)

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQueryUI Resizable for textareas.

Include jQuery UI library in your project

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

then in your jquery code call the line below

```
$("#MyTextAreaId").resizable({ });
```

Comment: It's not working. I added "@section MyCustomScripts
{
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#About" ).resizable();
  } );
</script>
}" in the beginning of my view, but I got error and it did not work. I'm using MVC 5

Comment: This is my code : ~{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<link href="/plugins/fileInput/css/fileinput.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/plugins/fileInput/js/fileinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

~section MyCustomScripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script> $( function() { $( "#About" ).resizable(); } ); </script> }
}
           replace ~ with @                     ~Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.About, 10, 300, new { htmlAttributes = new { ~class = "form-control" } })

Comment: and I get error : Object doesn't support property or method 'resizable'

Comment: ok,  can see why its not working. here is a poly fill you can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/resize-polyfill