# Textarea with flexible background image that resizes with text input

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have a `textarea` whose background is a hand-drawn box. I'd like for the `height` of the background image to stretch along with the text that goes in it. So when text is input beyond the `height`/`width` of the `textarea`, instead of a seeing a scrollbar, the image (along with the textbox itself) is resized to match the full height of the text. I assume this could be fixed with adding a `min-height: 200px`/`max-height:100%` for the `textarea` CSS but don't know how to implement it properly.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/FBihk.png]

The code I'm using is:

```
    textarea{ 
        background: #FFF url(box.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        width: 605px;
        height: 200px;
        line-height:20px;
        padding:30px;
        text-indent:3px;
        margin:0;
        border: none;
    }
```

```
<textarea type="text" class="textbox" size="14"></textarea>
```

EDIT: Just to clarify, this isn't the actual image we'll be using, designer is doing a much nicer version - just one I plonked together in paint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `<div>` with `contenteditable` and `display: inline-block;` can function like that with no code and works like a `<textarea>`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/sau9r/

HTML:

```
<div contenteditable>expaning textarea</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiR9T.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    min-height: 100px;
    min-width: 200px;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 30px 30px 40px 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Text areas do not normally resize to match the height of the text entered, so you'll need to use js. See [autosizing-textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477/autosizing-textarea) and [implementing-a-resizable-textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149421/implementing-a-resizable-textarea) for ways to do this. There are also jquery plugins available.

Stretching the background is going to be particularly difficult because it's hand-drawn.

I would suggest creating a `<div>` with a top border background image, followed by the `<textarea>` with a left and right sides background image **that can repeat vertically**, then add a `<div>` with a bottom border background image.