# How can I create a resizeable text area in Sencha Touch?

Tags: textbox, resize, sencha-touch, autoresize, sencha-touch-2

I have an application in Sencha Touch where I have a textareafield.  In Chrome, this is resizeable, but not when using an iPhone (I haven't tried on an Android device).

I need to have a text input area where people can enter text anything from one or two words long to many sentences.  So I need this to either **automatically resize**; have some way of **manually resizing** it; or some way of **scrolling** within it.

So far I have been unable to do any of these with Sencha Touch.  I would really appreciate it if someone can point me towards a workable solution.  It doesn't need to be any specific component in Sencha Touch.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to have javascript count the number of characters and then manually increase the height or width based on the number of characters in the text box. I don't know of any specific sencha touch solution.

Comment: @jb1785: For automatically changing the size, that would work (with a few problems to solve), but what about manually changing it?  Like the typical handle at the bottom of a textarea in most browsers?

Comment: This is mostly browser dependent. However you can implement it yourself by using a plugin. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149421/implementing-a-resizable-textarea, I don't know how much this helps you though since it looks like this requires yet another JS framework.

Comment: @jb1785: I'd really like to try stay away from adding yet another framework, but it may be worth trying to copy the way that it has been done and implement natively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a post on the Google Code blog explaining how they handled textarea auto growing in Mobile Gmail.  Here's the link: http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/07/gmail-for-mobile-html5-series.html

I threw together a quick sample with jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rFcUH/

I did it with Sencha Touch 1.1, though something similar should work with Sencha Touch 2.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give a sample. It works nicely.