# HTML text field size increase automatically

Tags: html, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch-2

My app is created using Sencha Touch and PhoneGap and is available on iOS and Android. The app has built in chat functionality. I'm trying to change the text text field where the text is typed to expand so the user can see what they have just typed.

For example, this is what it looks like now:

[image]

And here is what I would like it to look like:

[image]

So basically the text field expands to a maximum set height when a user is writing a message..

Any ideas?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522813/how-can-i-create-a-resizeable-text-area-in-sencha-touch

Comment: Tried to find something like that earlier with no luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check in your css file if there is written white-space:nowrap property for this.
Change this to :
white-space:normal; 
Now check.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this:

```
{
    xtype: 'textareafield',
    id: 'input_comment',
    placeHolder: 'Write a comment',
    name: 'newComment',
    clearIcon:false,
    flex:20,
    maxRows:1,
    minHeight:'60px',
    autoCapitalize:true,
    listeners:{
        keyup:function(){
            var textAreaEl = Ext.getCmp('input_comment').getComponent().input;

            if (textAreaEl) {
                if(textAreaEl.dom.scrollHeight < 121){
                    textAreaEl.dom.style.height = 'auto';
                    textAreaEl.dom.style.height = textAreaEl.dom.scrollHeight + "px";
                }
                else{
                    textAreaEl.dom.style.height = 'auto'
                    textAreaEl.dom.style.height = "120px";
                }
            }
            if(textAreaEl.dom.value == ""){
                textAreaEl.dom.style.height = '24px'
            }
        }
    }
},
```

It's important that the parent component doesn't have a height value defined