# textarea set height based on content js or jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

this is my code: (keep it simple)

```
<textarea style="height:100px;">
    $textareatext
</textarea>
```

- if `$textareatext` is 1 line long I want the height of textarea to fit
- if its 3, 5 or 10 lines...same thing.

The issue I am having is at `100px` the height is too big, but if I set it to `20px` and there are 10 lines then the textarea height is too small.
NOTE: values are preloaded via mysql. so I think it should count the lines,then set the height based on how many lines ?
Any suggestions?

I use Javascript and jQuery, or anything you would suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149421/implementing-a-resizable-textarea

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These may help. They're both jQuery plugins.

- [jQuery Elastic](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-elastic/)
- [Flexible Area](http://flaviusmatis.github.com/flexibleArea.js/)
- [Autogrow](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/autogrow)

**Edit**

```
var $textArea = $("#textarea-container");

resizeTextArea($textArea);

$textArea.off("keyup.textarea").on("keyup.textarea", function() {
    resizeTextArea($(this));
});

function resizeTextArea($element) {
    $element.height($element[0].scrollHeight);
}​
```

**This answer was provided by François Wahl, below.**

Comment: it need to resize after the page finish loaded. the variable $textareatext is read from the database.I know how to make it resize once I type there are plugins for that

Comment: Untested though, so may need a tweak.

Comment: var tAreaRows = $("#txtcorrect91").val().length / $("#txtcorrect91").attr('cols');
  alert(tAreaRows); returns NaN. and its not working

Comment: thanks PaparazzoKid,I ll figure it out the fiddle works thnks

Comment: @fogsy: Just updated the fiddle to alert the row number. Defo works. Good luck with the project.

Comment: @fogsy: I may see an issue. You may want to round the row number **down** to the nearest whole number, instead of normal rounding (where I added Math.Round()). At 5.5 rows, it's rounding to 6. Needs to be other way round.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid: When you have more than 4 rows of text at the start (6, 7, 8, etc) it seems to re-size to an incorrect row count. At 6 rows is re-sizes to 4 and at 8 rows it re-sizes to 5. If you use `scrollHeight` you don't need to calculate the area yourself. No need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid: `$("#myTArea").height($("#myTArea")[0].scrollHeight-15);` should work every time regardless of how many rows you start with. No need to calculate your own I think.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: I think you're right. My math is poop obviously. If fogsy comes back, hopefully he'll swap answers. I would fix this but yours is less code.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid: No worries, I'm not to worried about the selected answer, if you want feel free to update yours with the jQuery + scrollHeight and if it works, cool, that's the main thing :)

Comment: It is weird tho. I alert textarea value (say 784), I alert textarea cols (say 30), do the division and I get 26.1. I use Math.floor to bring it down to 26. It should be right, no? But it's not, it's like 5 lines more than it should be. Anyway, yeah I'll update the answer with the scrollHeight version. Thanks.

Comment: `scrollHeight` doesn't take into consideration pressing the "enter" key and breaking a new line. the height still stays the same as before, even though we practically have a new line..

Answer (score 9):

Remove the hard-coded height and give your `textarea` an id:

```
<textarea id="textarea-container">
    Line 1
    Line 2
    Line 3
    Line 4
</textarea>​
```

Using jQuery you can use the following to auto-resize at page load and then on the `keuUp` event as previously mentioned.

```
var $textArea = $("#textarea-container");

// Re-size to fit initial content as it is pre-loaded.
resizeTextArea($textArea);

// Remove this binding if you don't want to re-size on typing.
$textArea.off("keyup.textarea").on("keyup.textarea", function() {
    resizeTextArea($(this));
});

function resizeTextArea($element) {
    $element.height($element[0].scrollHeight);
}​
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/YjWeQ/1/)

Alternatively if all you care about is displaying it and removing the default row padding use this:

```
var $textArea = $("#textarea-container");
var nativeRowPadding = 15;

// Re-size to fit initial content.
resizeTextArea($textArea);

function resizeTextArea($element) {
    $element.height($element[0].scrollHeight-nativeRowPadding );
}​
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/kmaTR/)

Answer (score 5):

To make sure all your textareas keep up with their contents, increasing or decreasing height as you type, use the following:

```
$("textarea").on("input",function(){
   $(this).height("auto").height($(this)[0].scrollHeight);
}
```

it would actually be helpful to install this line of code on SO itself :)

Answer (score 2):

I made a OOP solution I use a lot:

```
$.fn.elasticHeight = function(){
    $( this ).height( 'auto' ).height( $( this )[ 0 ].scrollHeight );
    $( this ).on( "input", function(){
        $( this ).height( 'auto' ).height( $( this )[ 0 ].scrollHeight );
    } );
    return this;
};
```

then you just add the elasticHeight to your textarea like so:

```
$( "textarea" ).elasticHeight();
```

the `return this` is to make it bubble... so you can do this:

```
$( "textarea" ).elasticHeight().val( "default value" );
```

No need for fancy 3rd party plugins...

Answer (score 1):

Hey just the following 5 lines of code did the job for preloaded textareas

```
window.onload= function(){

    var inputs, index;

    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');

    for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) 
    {
    inputs[index].style.height=inputs[index].scrollHeight + 5
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple textarea support. Based off @François answer. [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YjWeQ/29/)

```
if ($(".textarea").length > 0) {
    $(".textarea").each(function () {
        resizeTextArea($(this));
        $(this).off("keyup.textarea").on("keyup.textarea", function () {
            resizeTextArea($(this));
        });
    });
}

function resizeTextArea($element) {
    $element.height($element[0].scrollHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

function updateHeight(el) {
  el.style.height = '';
  el.style.height = el.scrollHeight + 'px';
}

updateHeight(textarea);

textarea.addEventListener('input', () => updateHeight(textarea));
```

```html
<textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui, id? Aut dolorem nam iste. Asperiores minima nemo porro autem quidem. Quae quas dolore possimus sunt vitae quo ea incidunt. Sit repellendus at consequuntur fugiat quos, quisquam atque dolorem ipsa autem iure quod? Expedita eius cum asperiores obcaecati eaque laudantium libero aliquid ex doloremque modi incidunt, officiis velit reiciendis cupiditate necessitatibus harum quod repellendus officia quidem. Aliquid, temporibus. Nihil error cumque labore eius voluptas commodi accusamus eaque distinctio, facere dolores! Laudantium distinctio a quisquam quibusdam error nam quia ex cupiditate, fuga saepe maiores cumque enim corporis alias itaque recusandae vel! Omnis?</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea id='myText'></textarea>

var obj=document.getElementById('myText');
obj.onkeyup=function(){
if(obj.scrollHeight>obj.offsetHeight)obj.style.height=obj.scrollHeight+'px';
}
```

I presume the user is typing into the textarea

Comment: the value is preloaded via mysql

Answer (score 0):

The accepted code by François Wahl does not work when you are deleting lines in textarea - the height stays the same. Make sure you make textarea's height "auto" before getting it's scrollHeight:

```
function resizeTextArea($element) {
    $element.height("auto");
    $element.height($element[0].scrollHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most solutions are either not increasing AND decreasing the `textarea` height, OR too jumpy when you hit "Enter" to get to the next line, OR they are NOT working properly when the `textarea` height goes off the browser window limits.

Here is mine (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera):

```
$('.textareaInput').on('input', function(e) {
   if ($(this).outerHeight() > 162) {
       while($(this).outerHeight() < this.scrollHeight) {
           $(this).height($(this).height()+1);
       };

       while($(this).outerHeight() > this.scrollHeight) {
           $(this).height($(this).height()-1);
       };   

   } else {
       while($(this).outerHeight() < this.scrollHeight) {
           if ($(this).height())
           $(this).height($(this).height()+1);
       };
   }
});
```

... where 162 = 150(min-height) + 6(top padding) + 6(bottom padding):

```
.textareaInput {
    min-height:150px;
    padding: 6px 4px;
    overflow-y:hidden;    
}
```