# Limit height of TextArea based on content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap, to disable the contents of a TextArea as such:

```
<td>
  <textarea class="form-control disabled" id="message"></textarea>
</td>
```

which works fine, apart from the fact that I need to control the height as well, based on the content being rendered into the control.

Are there any HTML 5 tricks, or CSS tricks I can use to dynamically resize the height of the control based upon the text? Or can this only be achieved using JScript

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698956/textarea-set-height-based-on-content-js-or-jquery

Comment: David, this is showing textArea resizing on input, however the textarea is being populated on page load, using Ajax, so no user input.

Comment: @ChrisSpittles, i used the flexibleArea from your link. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1aupdsvk/)

HTML:

```
<textarea id="ta" class="form-control disabled" id="message"></textarea>
```

CSS:

```
textarea {

    resize:none;
}
```

SCRIPT:

```
$("#ta").keyup(function (e) {
    autoheight(this);
});

function autoheight(a) {
    if (!$(a).prop('scrollTop')) {
        do {
            var b = $(a).prop('scrollHeight');
            var h = $(a).height();
            $(a).height(h - 5);
        }
        while (b && (b != $(a).prop('scrollHeight')));
    };
    $(a).height($(a).prop('scrollHeight') + 20);
}

autoheight($("#ta"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following css:

```
textarea.form-control{
   position:absolute;
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: please try to improve your answer by providing details of what have you done and why you've done it. regards