# Auto-expanding textarea

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a simple auto-expanding textarea. This is my code:

```
textarea.onkeyup = function () {
  textarea.style.height = textarea.clientHeight + 'px';
}
```

But the textarea just keeps growing indefinitely as you type...

I know there is Dojo and a jQuery plugin for this, but would rather not have to use them. I looked at their implementation, and was initially using `scrollHeight` but that did the same thing.

You can start answering and play with the textarea for your answer to play with.

Comment: I edited a typo in the code, referencing the variable 'report' was a mistake I made just editing here for my question. It wasn't the cause of the infinitely growing textarea

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924655/how-do-i-make-an-expanding-textbox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a textarea with auto-resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize (30+ answers)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Reset the height before Using `scrollHeight` to expand/shrink the textarea correctly. `Math.min()` can be used to set a limit on the textarea's height.

Code:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
var heightLimit = 200; /* Maximum height: 200px */

textarea.oninput = function() {
  textarea.style.height = ""; /* Reset the height*/
  textarea.style.height = Math.min(textarea.scrollHeight, heightLimit) + "px";
};
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gjqWy/155**

Note: The [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.oninput) is not supported by IE8 and earlier. Use `keydown` or `keyup` with `onpaste` and/or `oncut` if you want to support this ancient browser as well.

Comment: +1: Nice... I was looking for a reliable way to do this. Does this account for the little nuances too, like pasting into the textarea, etc.?

Comment: FYI - I've posted a solution that allows you to limit by rows instead of pixels: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24824750/126574

Answer (score 11):

I've wanted to have the auto-expanding area to be limited by rows number (e.g 5 rows). I've considered using "em" units, for [Rob's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745840/126574) however, this is [error-prone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034544/textareas-rows-and-cols-attribute-in-css) and wouldn't take account stuff like padding, etc.

So this is what I came up with:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
var limitRows = 5;
var messageLastScrollHeight = textarea.scrollHeight;

textarea.oninput = function() {
    var rows = parseInt(textarea.getAttribute("rows"));
    // If we don't decrease the amount of rows, the scrollHeight would show the scrollHeight for all the rows
    // even if there is no text.
    textarea.setAttribute("rows", "1");

    if (rows < limitRows && textarea.scrollHeight > messageLastScrollHeight) {
        rows++;
    } else if (rows > 1 && textarea.scrollHeight < messageLastScrollHeight) {
        rows--;
    }

    messageLastScrollHeight = textarea.scrollHeight;
    textarea.setAttribute("rows", rows);
};
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cgSj3/**

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but cannot take into account pre-existing values, or pasted values that take up more than 1 row.

Comment: `var rows = textarea.rows`

Answer (score 4):

## 2022 Vanilla JS Solution

##### Note: I have only tested this in Chrome but it should work everywhere.

This will handle pasting, deleting, text-wrapping, manual returns, etc. & accounts for padding and box-sizing issues.

#### How it Works

1. Forces resize and all height properties to auto/none/0 etc to
   prevent interference with the event code.
2. Resets the rows attribute
   to 1 to get accurate `scrollHeight`.
3. Sets `overflow` to `hidden` and hard locks the current computed width (minus left/right border width and left/right padding widths), then forces `box-sizing` to `content-box` to get an accurate `line-height` and `scrollHeight` reading. `border-width` and `padding-inline` is also removed to keep the textarea width consistent when switching `box-sizing`. This all helps keep the math accurate when dealing with  text wrapping.
4. Grabs the computed `line-height` and `top/bottom-padding` pixel values.
5. Obtains the `scrollHeight` pixel value (rounded since chrome rounds
   and we're hoping to handle all browsers consistently).
6. Removes `overflow`, `box-sizing`, `width`, `padding-inline` and `border-width` overrides.
7. Subtracts `block_padding` from `scroll_height` then divides that by the `line_height` to get the needed `rows`. The `rows` value is rounded to the nearest integer since it will always be within ~.1 of the correct whole number.
8. The calculated `rows` value is applied as the
   `rows` attribute unless the `row_limit` is smaller, then the `row_limit` is used instead.

#### Edit / Update Details

I removed the loop code that was used figure out the row count because I was able to verify the math on the division formula works out within about .1 of the row count needed. Therefore a simple `Math.round()` ensures the row count is accurate. I was not able to break this in testing so if it turns out to be wrong please feel free to suggest a tweak.

I also ran into issues when `line-height` is not explicitly set on the text area as in that case the computed value for `line-height` comes back as `"normal"` and not the actual computed value. This new version accounts for this eventuality and handles it properly as well.

#### Layout Shift Possibility

I did not set the `textarea` to `position: absolute;` while swapping it's `box-sizing` out as I did not notice a need for it in my testing. It's worth mentioning because I suppose there could be a scenario where these minor changes might cause a layout shift depending on how the page is styled and if that happens you could add add that and then remove it along with the box-sizing override and removal.

#### Sample Code

(you only need the one JS function, everything else is just for the demo)

```js
function autosize(textarea_id, row_limit) {
  // Set default for row_limit parameter
  row_limit = parseInt(row_limit ?? '5');
  if (!row_limit) {
    row_limit = 5;
  }

  // Get the element
  const textarea = document.getElementById(textarea_id);

  // Set required styles for this to function properly.
  textarea.style.setProperty('resize', 'none');
  textarea.style.setProperty('min-height', '0');
  textarea.style.setProperty('max-height', 'none');
  textarea.style.setProperty('height', 'auto');

  // Set rows attribute to number of lines in content
  textarea.oninput = function() {

    // Reset rows attribute to get accurate scrollHeight
    textarea.setAttribute('rows', '1');

    // Get the computed values object reference
    const cs = getComputedStyle(textarea);

    // Force content-box for size accurate line-height calculation
    // Remove scrollbars, lock width (subtract inline padding and inline border widths)
    // and remove inline padding and borders to keep width consistent (for text wrapping accuracy)
    const inline_padding = parseFloat(cs['padding-left']) + parseFloat(cs['padding-right']);
    const inline_border_width = parseFloat(cs['border-left-width']) + parseFloat(cs['border-right-width']);
    textarea.style.setProperty('overflow', 'hidden', 'important');
    textarea.style.setProperty('width', (parseFloat(cs['width']) - inline_padding - inline_border_width) + 'px');
    textarea.style.setProperty('box-sizing', 'content-box');
    textarea.style.setProperty('padding-inline', '0');
    textarea.style.setProperty('border-width', '0');
    
    // Get the base line height, and top / bottom padding.
    const block_padding = parseFloat(cs['padding-top']) + parseFloat(cs['padding-bottom']);
    const line_height =
      // If line-height is not explicitly set, use the computed height value (ignore padding due to content-box)
      cs['line-height'] === 'normal' ? parseFloat(cs['height'])
      // Otherwise (line-height is explicitly set), use the computed line-height value.
      : parseFloat(cs['line-height']);

    // Get the scroll height (rounding to be safe to ensure cross browser consistency)
    const scroll_height = Math.round(textarea.scrollHeight);

    // Undo overflow, width, border-width, box-sizing & inline padding overrides
    textarea.style.removeProperty('width');
    textarea.style.removeProperty('box-sizing');
    textarea.style.removeProperty('padding-inline');
    textarea.style.removeProperty('border-width');
    textarea.style.removeProperty('overflow');

    // Subtract block_padding from scroll_height and divide that by our line_height to get the row count.
    // Round to nearest integer as it will always be within ~.1 of the correct whole number.
    const rows = Math.round((scroll_height - block_padding) / line_height);

    // Set the calculated rows attribute (limited by row_limit)
    textarea.setAttribute("rows", "" + Math.min(rows, row_limit));
  };

  // Trigger the event to set the initial rows value
  textarea.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {
    bubbles: true
  }));
}

autosize('textarea');
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 30rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  padding: .375rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="enter some text here :)"></textarea>
</body>
```

Comment: This pretty much worked perfect for me. I ended up turning it into an installable module: https://github.com/kodie/growfield and I gave you credit in the readme. Thank you!

Comment: It makes me very happy that someone found a use for this! Thanks for letting me know <3

Answer (score 3):

For those interested in a jQuery version of [Rob W's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745741/auto-expanding-textarea/7745840#7745840) solution:

```
var textarea = jQuery('.textarea');
textarea.on("input", function () {
    jQuery(this).css("height", ""); //reset the height
    jQuery(this).css("height", Math.min(jQuery(this).prop('scrollHeight'), 200) + "px");
});
```

Comment: Author stated solutions shout not use jquery.

Comment: Author stated they did not want to use a jQuery plugin. This solution is not a plugin, it is plain jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

...and if you need an infinitely expanding textarea (as I did), just do this:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");

textarea.oninput = function() {
  textarea.style.height = ""; /* Reset the height*/
  textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + "px";
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Split line to array with newline charaters and set it's length to `rows`:

```js
textarea.addEventListener('input', 
    e => e.target.rows = e.target.value.split('\n').length
);
```

Answer (score 0):

using

`<div contentEditable></div>`

may also do the same work, expanding it self, and requires no js

Comment: This does completely nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the accepted answer, my function cares about `padding-{top,bottom}` and `border-{top,bottom}-width`. And it has many parameters. Note that it doesn't set `window.addEventListener('resize')`

Function:

```js
// @author Arzet Ro, 2021 <arzeth0@gmail.com>
// @license CC0 (Creative Commons Zero v1.0 Universal) (i.e. Public Domain)
// @source https://stackoverflow.com/a/70341077/332012
// Useful for elements with overflow-y: scroll and <textarea>
// Tested only on <textarea> in desktop Firefox 95 and desktop Chromium 96.
export function autoResizeScrollableElement (
    el: HTMLElement,
    {
        canShrink = true,
        minHeightPx = 0,
        maxHeightPx,
        minLines,
        maxLines,
    }: {
        canShrink?: boolean,
        minHeightPx?: number,
        maxHeightPx?: number,
        minLines?: number,
        maxLines?: number,
    } = {}
): void
{
    const FN_NAME = 'autoResizeScrollableElement'
    if (
        typeof minLines !== 'undefined'
        && minLines !== null
        && Number.isNaN(+minLines)
    )
    {
        console.warn(
            '%O(el=%O):: minLines (%O) as a number is NaN',
            FN_NAME, el, minLines
        )
    }
    if (
        typeof maxLines !== 'undefined'
        && maxLines !== null
        && Number.isNaN(+maxLines)
    )
    {
        console.warn(
            '%O(el=%O):: maxLines (%O) as a number is NaN',
            FN_NAME, el, maxLines
        )
    }
    canShrink = (
        canShrink === true
        ||
        // @ts-ignore
        canShrink === 1 || canShrink === void 0 || canShrink === null
    )

    const style = window.getComputedStyle(el)
    const unpreparedLineHeight = style.getPropertyValue('line-height')
    if (unpreparedLineHeight === 'normal')
    {
        console.error('%O(el=%O):: line-height is unset', FN_NAME, el)
    }
    const lineHeightPx: number = (
        unpreparedLineHeight === 'normal'
        ? 1.15 * parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('font-size')) // 1.15 is a wrong number
        : parseFloat(unpreparedLineHeight)
    )

    // @ts-ignore
    minHeightPx = parseFloat(minHeightPx || 0) || 0
    //minHeight = Math.max(lineHeightPx, parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('min-height')))
    // @ts-ignore
    maxHeightPx = parseFloat(maxHeightPx || 0) || Infinity
    minLines = (
        minLines
        ? (
            Math.round(+minLines || 0) > 1
            ? Math.round(+minLines || 0)
            : 1
        )
        : 1
    )
    maxLines = (
        maxLines
        ? (Math.round(+maxLines || 0) || Infinity)
        : Infinity
    )
    //console.log('%O:: old ov.x=%O ov.y=%O, ov=%O', FN_NAME, style.getPropertyValue('overflow-x'), style.getPropertyValue('overflow-y'), style.getPropertyValue('overflow'))
    /*if (overflowY !== 'scroll' && overflowY === 'hidden')
    {
        console.warn('%O:: setting overflow-y to scroll', FN_NAME)
    }*/
    if (minLines > maxLines)
    {
        console.warn(
            '%O(el=%O):: minLines (%O) > maxLines (%O), '
            + 'therefore both parameters are ignored',
            FN_NAME, el, minLines, maxLines
        )
        minLines = 1
        maxLines = Infinity
    }
    if (minHeightPx > maxHeightPx)
    {
        console.warn(
            '%O(el=%O):: minHeightPx (%O) > maxHeightPx (%O), '
            + 'therefore both parameters are ignored',
            FN_NAME, el, minHeightPx, maxHeightPx
        )
        minHeightPx = 0
        maxHeightPx = Infinity
    }
    const topBottomBorderWidths: number = (
        parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('border-top-width'))
        + parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('border-bottom-width'))
    )
    let verticalPaddings: number = 0
    if (style.getPropertyValue('box-sizing') === 'border-box')
    {
        verticalPaddings += (
            parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('padding-top'))
            + parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('padding-bottom'))
            + topBottomBorderWidths
        )
    }
    else
    {
        console.warn(
            '%O(el=%O):: has `box-sizing: content-box`'
            + ' which is untested; you should set it to border-box. Continuing anyway.',
            FN_NAME, el
        )
    }
    const oldHeightPx = parseFloat(style.height)
    if (el.tagName === 'TEXTAREA')
    {
        el.setAttribute('rows', '1')
        //el.style.overflowY = 'hidden'
    }
    // @ts-ignore
    const oldScrollbarWidth: string|void = el.style.scrollbarWidth
    el.style.height = ''

    // Even when there is nothing to scroll,
    // it causes an extra height at the bottom in the content area (tried Firefox 95).
    // scrollbar-width is present only on Firefox 64+,
    // other browsers use ::-webkit-scrollbar
    // @ts-ignore
    el.style.scrollbarWidth = 'none'

    const maxHeightForMinLines = lineHeightPx * minLines + verticalPaddings // can be float
    // .scrollHeight is always an integer unfortunately
    const scrollHeight = el.scrollHeight + topBottomBorderWidths
    /*console.log(
        '%O:: lineHeightPx=%O * minLines=%O + verticalPaddings=%O, el.scrollHeight=%O, scrollHeight=%O',
        FN_NAME, lineHeightPx, minLines, verticalPaddings,
        el.scrollHeight, scrollHeight
    )*/
    const newHeightPx = Math.max(
        canShrink === true ? minHeightPx : oldHeightPx,
        Math.min(
            maxHeightPx,
            Math.max(
                maxHeightForMinLines,
                Math.min(
                    Math.max(scrollHeight, maxHeightForMinLines)
                    - Math.min(scrollHeight, maxHeightForMinLines) < 1
                    ? maxHeightForMinLines
                    : scrollHeight,
                    (
                        maxLines > 0 && maxLines !== Infinity
                        ? lineHeightPx * maxLines + verticalPaddings
                        : Infinity
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    // @ts-ignore
    el.style.scrollbarWidth = oldScrollbarWidth
    if (!Number.isFinite(newHeightPx) || newHeightPx < 0)
    {
        console.error(
            '%O(el=%O):: BUG:: Invalid return value: `%O`',
            FN_NAME, el, newHeightPx
        )
        return
    }
    el.style.height = newHeightPx + 'px'
    //console.log('%O:: height: %O → %O', FN_NAME, oldHeightPx, newHeightPx)
    /*if (el.tagName === 'TEXTAREA' && el.scrollHeight > newHeightPx)
    {
        el.style.overflowY = 'scroll'
    }*/
}
```

Usage with React (TypeScript):

```js
<textarea
    onKeyDown={(e) => {
        if (!(e.key === 'Enter' && !e.shiftKey)) return true
        e.preventDefault()
        // send the message, then this.scrollToTheBottom()
        return false
    }}
    onChange={(e) => {
        if (this.state.isSending)
        {
            e.preventDefault()
            return false
        }
        this.setState({
            pendingMessage: e.currentTarget.value
        }, () => {
            const el = this.chatSendMsgRef.current!
            engine.autoResizeScrollableElement(el, {maxLines: 5})
        })
        return true
    }}
/>
```

For React `onChange` is like `oninput` in HTML5, so if you don't use React, then use the `input` event.

---

One of the answers uses `rows` attribute (instead of CSS's `height` as my code above does), here's an alternative implementation that doesn't use outside variables (BUT just like that answer there is a bug: because `rows` is temporaily set to 1, something bad happens with `<html>`'s scrollTop when you input AND `<html>` can be scrolled):

```js
// @author Arzet Ro, 2021 <arzeth0@gmail.com>
// @license CC0 (Creative Commons Zero v1.0 Universal) (i.e. Public Domain)
// @source https://stackoverflow.com/a/70341077/332012
function autoResizeTextareaByChangingRows (
    el,
    {minLines, maxLines}
)
{
    const FN_NAME = 'autoResizeTextareaByChangingRows'
    if (
        typeof minLines !== 'undefined'
        && minLines !== null
        && Number.isNaN(+minLines)
    )
    {
        console.warn('%O:: minLines (%O) as a number is NaN', FN_NAME, minLines)
    }
    if (
        typeof maxLines !== 'undefined'
        && maxLines !== null
        && Number.isNaN(+maxLines)
    )
    {
        console.warn('%O:: maxLines (%O) as a number is NaN', FN_NAME, maxLines)
    }
    minLines = (
        minLines
        ? (
            Math.round(+minLines || 0) > 1
            ? Math.round(+minLines || 0)
            : 1
        )
        : 1
    )
    maxLines = (
        maxLines
        ? (Math.round(+maxLines || 0) || Infinity)
        : Infinity
    )
    el.setAttribute(
        'rows',
        '1',
    )
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(el)
    const unpreparedLineHeight = style.getPropertyValue('line-height')
    if (unpreparedLineHeight === 'normal')
    {
        console.error('%O:: line-height is unset for %O', FN_NAME, el)
    }
    const rows = Math.max(minLines, Math.min(maxLines,
        Math.round(
            (
                el.scrollHeight
                - parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('padding-top'))
                - parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('padding-bottom'))
            ) / (
                unpreparedLineHeight === 'normal'
                ? 1.15 * parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('font-size')) // 1.15 is a wrong number
                : parseFloat(unpreparedLineHeight)
            )
        )
   ))
    el.setAttribute(
        'rows',
        rows.toString()
    )
}

const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')
textarea.oninput = function ()
{
    autoResizeTextareaByChangingRows(textarea, {maxLines: 5})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using Angular and having the same issue, use

```html
<textarea cdkTextareaAutosize formControlName="description" name="description" matInput placeholder="Description"></textarea>
```

The key here is `cdkTextareaAutosize` which will automatically resize the textarea to fit its content. [Read more](https://material.angular.io/cdk/text-field/api#CdkTextareaAutosize) here.

I hope this helps someone.