# Text box size should grow when typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

I am looking for a effect in the text box. 
Initially the size of the text box will be small and when type in, the text box should grow bigger. Is there any jquery plugin available for this effect? If not how can this be achieved.?

Comment: What have you tried? How about starting with Google..? Result #3 looks useful. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=textarea%20grow%20with%20text&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_nf=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=a366a72422fd9740&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb

Comment: You need to accept some answers first

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745741/auto-expanding-textarea

Comment: I mam ready to accept but for that my reputation should be 15

Comment: You only need 1 rep to click on the checkmark, which is accept. I've given you 5 rep so you can also upvote (up arrow) some of those answers :)

Comment: thank you I have up voted the answers. I will mark them answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#mytextbox").keyup(function() {
    $(this).attr("maxLength", $(this).attr("maxLength") + 1);
    $(this).attr("size", $(this).attr("size") + 1);
});
```

Be aware that if the user presses a function key with the textbox focused, the size will increase regardless. You should instead monitor the textbox for changes in its value:

```
$("#mytextbox").keyup(function() {
    $(this).attr("size", $(this).val().length + 1);
});
```

Note that the second method will also support copy/pasting into the input field, whereas the first one will not, although you'll have to make sure the user has enough room to copy something in (right now, the size is set to +1 of the current value, meaning the user can only input one character at a time before the size is increased).

Comment: Oops, edited my answer, `maxlength` should be `maxLength`. Don't forget to accept this answer if it works for you!

Comment: maxlength isn't the same as physical size. And capitalization is irrelevant in HTML attributes.

Comment: Woops, you need to modify the `size` attribute as well. :D

Comment: After jsFiddling my answer, it appears that you don't need to set maxlength at all. This work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/HeyJavascript/MvaUz/ :D

Answer (score 2):

```
var $text = $('myselector')
$text.keyup(function() {
    $(this).attr({size : $(this).val().length});
});
```

This takes the size directly from the string length of whatever is input in the textbox.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer won't let the user type, as the size will automatically equal what's already in the text box, meaning the user won't be able to put any new text in. Also, there's no need to pass in an object into the `.attr()` function if you're only modifying one variable. Just use `$(this).attr("size", $(this).val().length);`

Comment: Assuming the textbox has a default/starting size it works fine.

Comment: Oops, you're right, I forgot that length is actually one greater than the amount of characters in the string, because the characters are 0 indexed. This works fine. :D

Answer (score -1):

have a look at this jquery plugin:

http://www.unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/

Comment: -1 to the person(s) behind that site. The demo on the linked page doesn't work! (I'm on Chrome.)

Comment: i'm using chrome and it works for me? did you try this?

http://jsfiddle.net/janjarfalk/r3Ekw/

Comment: The jsfiddle works as-is, but the linked page is still buggy. It seems like the "elastic" is doing it's thing with the textarea, but the rest of the page doesn't play along...