# CSS - any way to make a textarea or input box elastic?

Tags: css, input, textarea

I found many javascript plugins to make a textarea or input box elastic but what i'm wondering is:

is it possible to make something like this http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/ in pure css?

Comment: I personally doesn't understand the question. Could you provide some examples that you checked (please update your question with links, not posting comments).

Comment: @Minister better now? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is **no**, you cannot accomplish that using pure CSS, you cannot calculate how many letters did the user typed, what's the `height` of the `textarea` and how much you should increase proportionally while the user is typing.

So that's best suited if you use jQuery or JavaScript and increase the `height` on `onkeyup` or `onchange` event.

The very best in least JavaScript you can get is [this](http://lea.verou.me/scripts/elastic-textarea/)

---

Or transit the element on focus if you don't want to throw the big box on load...

```
textarea {
   height: 100px;
   width: 300px;
   -webkit-transition: all .5s;
   -moz-transition: all .5s;
   transition: all .5s;
   /* Used transition just to animate the resize, if not 
      required can be removed */
}

textarea:focus {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/u46qX/)

---

As you requested for minimal JavaScript to be used.. you can refer Rob's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745840/1542290)

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
var heightLimit = 200; /* Maximum height: 200px */

textarea.oninput = function() {
  textarea.style.height = ""; /* Reset the height*/
  textarea.style.height = Math.min(textarea.scrollHeight, heightLimit) + "px";
};
```

<sup>Credits for code - Rob W</sup>

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gjqWy/155)

Comment: I recommend `oninput` over `onkeydown`, see my edited answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7745840/1542290 (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gjqWy/155)

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, it is not possible using pure CSS and a textarea. However, you can use an editable div to do that. Here is an example of what you could do that creates a textarea like box that expands as the user types.

```
<div id="editable" contenteditable></div>
<style>
div#editable{
    min-height: 2em;
    height: auto;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
div#editable:focus {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
```

Comment: man this could be awesome, do you know or have any idea on how to fake the placeholder tho?

Comment: @sbaaaang don't think that this will be submitted just like textboxes in the form

Comment: @Mr.Alien sure man just since i'm using a js form i can easly get div content :P  if i can get how to fake the placeholder this solves a lot

Comment: @sbaaaang but won't make any sense, you are just increasing your work by writing more JS compared to a small plugin file, which will accomplish job easily...

Comment: Why do you need to use pure CSS?

Comment: Yea, now thats my question as well

Comment: @Mr.Alien 3 lines vs 3/4 kb at least? :O , also i can't get any javascript plugin to work good actually only jquery but i'm not using frameworks and libray :(

Comment: @sbaaaang still, I would suggest you to stick with the standards, who knows what device would act with `contenteditable`? and as far as placeholder goes, you can use `onblur` and `onfocus` if you are looking forward to this solution

Comment: @Mr.Alien man the problem is i can't find any pure js plugin to achieve this, i don't use any js library like jquery and company, i just need pure js or hacks, for example this one http://lea.verou.me/scripts/elastic-textarea/ it bumps on chrome :/ it's really bad one :(

Comment: @sbaaaang hmmmm, anyways that was just my personal suggestion :) also, as far as User Interface goes, this is really uncomfy.

Comment: yeah i'm gonna accept your answer man but please put a better link for js plugin :D that is awful really :D @Mr. Alien

Comment: thanks @eliospizzaman your trick is awesome i'll try something , just the answer was about css so i can't accept your answer cause it's html5 but really really thanks

Comment: @sbaaaang lol accept this answer as it suffices your needs, but I was just suggesting you some standard way nothing else :) but anyways if I got pure JS solution, I will share for sure

Comment: @Mr.Alien lol that "if i got" you know ti means you'll never right? :D i'll accept your when plugin comes up lol , i can't accept this answer is not about css

Comment: @Mr.Alien lol and... don't forget ... "lightweight and well written one" :D ahah

Comment: @sbaaaang can you get shorter than [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7745840/1542290)?

Comment: @Mr.Alien not really :D accepted answer man, put that link inside it's really good resource and thanks a ton

Comment: @sbaaaang done already :) and you welcome ...

Comment: Ah, it started with CSS-only solution and almost ended with a new form plugin! :-) If @sbaaaang (it seems he is a very experienced member of the community) has entered a few more links for examples, it could have saved a few hours of chat (and a few hours of you guys) :-)

Comment: @Minister nope man :D the answer is clear i can reproduce in pure CSS so we ended up with a good js resource, but the answer is clear to me :)