# What is the easiest way to let a textarea autogrow in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, textarea

I've seen all kind of jquery plugins for autogrowing a textarea. But I hope there may be an easy way to let a textarea element autogrow in pure javascript (anno 2015).

I'm only targeting modern browsers. But I also appreciate answers that target older browsers.

Comment: Have you tried anything which is not working ?

Comment: Yup, I have got some things working with jquery. Could translate that to javascript of course. But I was just wondering for an easier way.

Comment: Using `contentEditable` https://jsfiddle.net/ye3s6j23/

Comment: please refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745741/auto-expanding-textarea

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work. Not tested it that well though.

```
<textarea></textarea>
<script>
    var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
    textarea.addEventListener('input', function() {
        textarea.style.height = 'auto';
        textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + 'px';
    });
</script>
```