# Prevent form element from spanning horizontally

Tags: jquery-mobile

By default form elements (input) in jQuery Mobile span over the full width of the screen.

How can I make them fit to the size of their content ?

Comment: Have a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392493/adjust-width-of-input-field-to-its-input


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392493/adjust-width-of-input-field-to-its-input

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data-inline="true"` on buttons and selects to make them span to the width of their content.