# How do i use jquery to edit tables in the django manager?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I have a table output in Django from my DB into HTML.
I want to make it so the width for my fields ajusts to the text size, i found some js here: 
[Adjust width of input field to its input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392493/adjust-width-of-input-field-to-its-input)
...but when i paste the code to my .js files it doesnt change the fields at all on the page. this is my css code currently

```
     table#infos td input {
            width:4em;
        }

        table#infos td textarea {
             width:6em;
             height:2em;
}
```

and this is an eg of some of the html that isnt being changed properly

```
<tbody>
                <tr>

                <td>
                <div class="resizing-input">
                    <span class="sort_value" style="display:none;">1</span>
                    <input id="id_form-0-id" min="0" name="form-0-id" type="number" value="1" />
                </div>
            </td> 
<--etc--!>
```

the inputs id's are auto generated from the db column names etc
the jquery i tried to use was from this
http://jsfiddle.net/7pccrdbw/2/

Comment: The input is not inside the `sort_value` span, so that second selector won't work.

Comment: i dont think that affects the js though. even if i delete that part of the css it doesnt work. even if i delete ALL the css it doesnt work...