# How do I remove extra space from a input field of type date

Tags: html, css

I have a div with some inputs, one of type date and I want to remove the whitespace from the element

here is the code

```
<div class="form-group form-inline">
        <input id="jumbotronSearch" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Location" min="5" max="50" required/> 
        <input id="jumbotronDate" type="date" class="form-control input-lg" value="@DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString()" readonly/>
        <button id="jumbotronSearch" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Search</button>
    </div>
```

and here is what it looks like. I want to remvove all the extra space after the date.

I tried setting the css width to 100% and white-space: nowrap but that didn't do it.

[image]

Comment: Set the width to a lower amount: `width: 150px;`

Comment: I don't want a hard coded value, I want it to be responsive! Also the date string might change length.

Comment: You'll probably have to use !important because you're dealing with Bootstrap

Like so: 
white-space:nowrap !important; (or whatever property lets you fix what you want)

Comment: I don't believe this can be done with CSS, however perhaps someone else can correct me on that if I'm mistaken. Otherwise, have a look at this question: [Adjust Width of Input Field to its Input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392493/adjust-width-of-input-field-to-its-input)

Answer (score 0):

For a responsive solution have you tried changing this:

```
<input id="jumbotronDate" type="date" class="form-control input-lg" value="@DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString()" readonly/>
```

to

```
<input id="jumbotronDate" type="date" class="form-control form-date input-lg" value="@DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString()" readonly/>
```

Then in the css

```
.form-date{max-width:60%}
```

or if there is only one date on your page

```
#jumbotronDate{max-width:60%}
```

As there is a bootstrap value set for the width of the date, so use max-width to override it, or add `!important` to override any bootstrap constraints.