# Javascript:Adjust input field width based on text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement auto sized text field based on the solution from this
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392493/adjust-width-of-input-field-to-its-input)

```
<input style="width:20px;" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 5) + 'px';"  ng-model="questionButtons[$index].title" type="text" class="edt_spn active" >
```

it works fine however when the user deletes characters width is not adjusting

```html
<input style="width:20px;" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 5) + 'px';"  ng-model="questionButtons[$index].title" type="text" class="edt_spn active" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Try onkeyup event.

```html
<input style="width:20px;" onkeyup="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 5) + 'px';console.log(this.value.length);"  ng-model="questionButtons[$index].title" type="text" class="edt_spn active" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best variant is to use `oninput` event.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input):

> The DOM input event is fired synchronously when the value of an <input>, <select>, or <textarea> element is changed.

```html
<input style="width:20px;"  oninput="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 5) + 'px';"  ng-model="questionButtons[$index].title" type="text" class="edt_spn active" >
```