# Add clear cross button to text/search input and make it float next to text

Tags: html, css

I want to add a clear button to a text field that floats after the text in the input. Is there an easy way to do this using a search type input field?

```
<input type="search">
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you use javascript or Jquery?

Comment: In your own attempts how far did you get? Where did it/they go wrong, in what way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to copy the input's text into a hidden `<span>`, and move the reset button according to the width of the `<span>`. (This is inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/14855810/3469273.)

```js
var search = document.getElementById("search"),
    reset = document.getElementById("reset"),
    measure = document.getElementById("measure");

search.addEventListener("input", onInput);
reset.addEventListener("click", onInput);

function onInput() {
  measure.textContent = this.value;
  reset.style.left = measure.offsetWidth + 'px';
  
  console.log(measure.offsetWidth);
};
```

```css
form {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem;
}

#search,
#measure {
  padding: .5rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  white-space: pre; /* white-spaces will work effectively */
}

#search {
  width: 100%;
}

#reset {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #999;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#measure {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="search" type="search" />
  <input id="reset" type="reset" value="X">
</form>

<span id="measure"></span>
```

Comment: I can achieve the desired effect easier than that. I want to know if it's possible to style it in the desired way

Comment: To make the clear button follow the text, you'll need JavaScript.

Comment: How do I go about doing this then?

Comment: You'll need to dynamically calculate the width of the input's value. You can either do this based on the number of characters (easier but less accurate), or its actual value (harder but more accurate). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392493/adjust-width-of-input-field-to-its-input for more info.

Comment: I've edited my response to use JavaScript, giving a result more like what you want. (I suggest adding a "JavaScript" tag to your question, if you're willing to use it.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a button to clear the content of the input
Here's the code for the requirement:

```
<input id = "inputBox" class="inputBox" type="search">
<button class="clear-button" onclick="myfunction()">Clear</button>

<script>
    function myfunction(){
        document.getElementById("inputBox").value = ""
    }
</script>
```