# CSS of custom card to buy stocks (in percentage)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Please help me fix CSS of the following custom card inside modal box.

```
<!--Card-->
<div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
         <input type="text" id="market-search" onkeyup="marketSearch()" placeholder="Search for stock names..">
         <i class="fa fa-times" data-dismiss="modal"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="card stock-card" data-name="{{ stock.name }}">
               <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">ABB India Ltd.</h4>
                  <div class="market-info">
                     <p class="card-text stock-info"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/finance?q=NSE:{{ stock.code }}">Details</a></p>
                     <p class="card-text stock-info up" id="diff"> 9.45
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     </p>
                     <p class="card-text stock-info"><strong>$</strong> <span id="price">1340</span></p>
                     <p class="card-text stock-info">ABB</p>
                     <input id="input_{{stock.code}}"/>
                     <a style="white-space:nowrap" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-success " onclick=insertRow("{{stock.code}}","{{stock.name|to_and}}","{{stock.price}}","{{stock.diff}}")>Buy</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My card looks like below after getting rendered.

[image]

I am using CSS from the bootstrap. Here are different CSS classes that I am overriding.

```
.card {
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.card .card-title {
    font-weight: 300;
}

.card .market-info .card-text {
    font-weight: 400;
}

.card .market-info .stock-info
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 1em;
    text-align: right;
}

.card .market-info .up {
    color: green;
}

.card .market-info .down {
    color: red;
}
```

I want to make this modal box and the card clean, intuitive and professional.

1. As a first step, I would like to keep everything in the card on a single line. i.e. I want to shift the input box (reduce its size, put a placeholder that the value that can be entered in input box has to be in percentage) and the buy button (make it short and intuitive) in the first line itself.
2. The modal box should have a scroller.

I am not able to do it. Any help here is highly appreciated?

Link to codepen https://codepen.io/agrawalo/pen/NWKaWMm

Comment: Can you make code snipped or upload example to codepen, please?

Comment: do you want equal columns ?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph whatever looks good in single line :)

Comment: @AndrewSavetchuk added link to codepen and added more details to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add This CSS

```
.card .market-info p{
  margin:0;
}
.card .market-info input{
  max-width:60px;
  margin-right:5px;
}
.card .market-info{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

OR

```
  .card .market-info input{
  max-width:60px;
  padding:6px;
  margin-right:5px;
}
.card .market-info .stock-info
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;/*Change HERE*/
    text-align: right;
}
.card .market-info{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.card .market-info p{
  margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Please check the codepen, after adding this price and arrow goes to the next line. Maybe this is happening because the modal width is less. Also, there is no scroller in the modal box. Can you tell how can I fix all of these?

Comment: Also, the height of buy button, the height of input box and height of other components in the row do not match.

Comment: Thanks, can't we make the height of buy button and input box equal?

Comment: add padding on input  `padding: 6px;`

Comment: ok, still there are two issues

1. No Scroller in the modal box. 2. Width of the modal box is less hence things are not coming as expected

Comment: add screenshot here

Comment: Added in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198808/discussion-between-lalji-tadhani-and-lokesh-agrawal).

Answer (score 1):

You can try `flexbox` and set `overflow` to `auto`. Checkout this:

```css
.card {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.card .card-title {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.card .market-info .card-text {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.card .market-info .stock-info {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 1em;
  text-align: right;
}

.card .market-info .up {
  color: green;
}

.card .market-info .down {
  color: red;
}


/*added code*/

.market-info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

.card .market-info>p.stock-info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!--Card-->
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <input type="text" id="market-search" onkeyup="marketSearch()" placeholder="Search for stock names.." onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';">
      <i class="fa fa-times" data-dismiss="modal"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card stock-card" data-name="{{ stock.name }}">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">ABB India Ltd.</h4>
            <div class="market-info">
              <p class="card-text stock-info"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/finance?q=NSE:{{ stock.code }}">Details</a></p>
              <p class="card-text stock-info up" id="diff"> 9.45
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </p>
              <p class="card-text stock-info"><strong>$</strong> <span id="price">1340</span></p>
              <p class="card-text stock-info">ABB</p>
              <input id="input_{{stock.code}}" />
              <a style="white-space:nowrap" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-success " onclick=insertRow( "{{stock.code}}", "{{stock.name|to_and}}", "{{stock.price}}", "{{stock.diff}}")>Buy</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: I have edited my post. Now all the arrow and $ symbol will not go on the other line. If you also want to make input box of dynamic width, add this code:

```
onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';"
```

Refer: [Adjust width of input field to its input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392493/adjust-width-of-input-field-to-its-input)

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Actually I am rendering these card inside the modal box. Please see the updated question.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal what's the difference? :|

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal do you want `h3` to be in the same line as well?

Comment: h3? which h3 you are talking about?

Comment: Pardon, I meant `h4`

Comment: No, thats a title