# How to resize ion-input to text-width

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic-framework, input

### How do you resize an ionic input to fit its content?

[image: Where it's currently...]
[image: What it should look like...]- What it **should** look like

### What I've tried

1. [size]="1" ~ doesn't change ion-input at all, only HTML input
2. width: fit-content;
3. updateWidth(value){...} ~ only works well with Monospace fonts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43488899/5909026

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib thanks for the reference, but this is the third point in: what I've tried so far