# Adjust width of input field to its input, get rid of right space

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs3

I am using vue

I want to auto increment the input by using my input component.

```
<input
      type="text"
      v-model="inputValue"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
      oninput="this.size = this.value.length"
      @keyup="handleInput"
      @blur="handleBlur"
      style="max-width: 100%" />
```

My Problem is that the content has always more space than needed. example

[image]

When using a span the problem doesn't seem to appear.

```
  <span
        class="input"
        role="textbox"
        :data-placeholder="placeholder"
        oninput="this.size = this.value.length"
        contenteditable="true"
        @keyup="handleInput"
        style="max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%">
        {{ value }}
      </span>
```

[image]

How can I get rid of this space using an Input?

```html
<input
      type="text"
      v-model="inputValue"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
      oninput="this.size = this.value.length"
      @keyup="handleInput"
      @blur="handleBlur"
      style="max-width: 100%" />
```

Comment: The answer is given here already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392493/adjust-width-of-input-field-to-its-input

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adjust width of input field to its input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392493/adjust-width-of-input-field-to-its-input)