# How to auto-size a textarea in height?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I set the width of a textarea to 100%, but now I need to know how many characters can fit in one row.

I'm trying to write a javascript function to auto-grow/shrink a textarea. I'm trying to keep from using jquery since I just need this one function.

My logic is to `rows = textarea.value.split('\n')`, iterate through `rows` and `count += rows[i].length/textarea.cols`, then `count += rows.length`, and finally `textarea.rows = count`. The only problem is that `count` is too large because `textarea.cols` is too small.

Comment: This is a tough problem. For most fonts, it is impossible to predict a fixed number of allowed characters because each character has a different width. You will need to use a monospaced font like courier to do this

Comment: Why use JavaScript? Can you use CSS?
#textareaId { width:100%; }

Comment: @Pekka - always enjoying reading your answers/comments

Comment: @ifaour thank you! It still is fun to write here, or even just think aloud in comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a textarea with auto-resize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize)

Answer (score 7):

This function will set the height of the element (textarea, in your case) to the browser's default height. If that causes a scrollbar to appear, the height will be switched to the actually needed height.

```
function autoHeight(element){
    element.style.height='auto';
    element.style.height=element.scrollHeight+'px';
}
```

If you don't like the browser's default height, you can change that to some other default value of your own, of course.

Comment: +1 for one of the best answers on the subject I have found. The only one thing that I would change is to use `element.style.height=0;` to make sure the `textarea` height is as little as possible. Otherwise, in case of the browser I am using, it is at least two rows.

Comment: Thanks. You could also add a `minHeight` parameter to the function. A height of 0 might cause flickering, if you use this in a keyup event, for example.

Comment: Best solution I've seen so far!

Answer (score 1):

Try this and enjoy:

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("YourTextArea");
var limit = 50; //height limit

textarea.oninput = function() {
  textarea.style.height = "";
  textarea.style.height = Math.min(textarea.scrollHeight, limit) + "px";
};
```

```css
textarea {
    width: 99%;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="YourTextArea"></textarea>
```