# JQuery TextArea AutoGrow Plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find the best textarea autogrow plugin.  I need one which resizes the textarea even when I paste into it.  Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use it??
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/autogrowtextarea

Or another updated version of this plugin here: https://github.com/ro31337/jquery.ns-autogrow

Comment: doesn't autoresize on paste... :(

Comment: I had issues with the jquery.ns-autogrow cause of certain styling choices. I used the autosize.js and it worked out of box and with one line of code to set the auto size.

Answer (score 7):

Elastic is a very good one, and it handles CTRL + V cases too.

You can visit the [website](http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/) and try out a demo.

Comment: +1 because Elastic rocks and is just what I needed! :) Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: Elastic is bad for 2 reasons: (1) its slow and really laggy, even in Google Chrome and (2) if minify the script in your deploy, it will break the JS.

Comment: Okay and what plugin is better in your opinion?

Answer (score 4):

This is the one I ended up using. Working great so far!

http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

The JQuery Elastic plugin is slow and didn't work for me in IE8.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following method, in `jQuery`.

```
setInterval(function(){
      $(name_textarea).css('height', $(name_textarea)[0].scrollHeight+2+'px')
},100);
```

Try it, you could possibly change the `scrollHeight` to obtain the best results.

Comment: I ended up using $(name_textarea).prop("scrollHeight") in order to get scroll height.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Advanced Textarea. Download from http://www.jscripts.info

- Auto-Height Textarea
- Returns Plain Text and HTML Content
- Automatic URL and Email recognition
- HTML Tags Filter

Answer (score 0):

i made another one plugin to do this, check it here:
https://github.com/AndrewDryga/jQuery.Textarea.Autoresize

Answer (score 0):

"I need one which resizes the textarea even when I paste into it"

this method also listen for copy/paste events:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5346855/4481831

I think on modern browsers those events can be replaced with "input" event, but on older browser this method will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-expand of text area can be accomplished **without** plugin. For example:

```
 var change_textarea = function() {
   jQuery('#your_textarea').on( 'change keyup keydown paste cut', 'textarea', 
   function(){
     jQuery(this).height(0).height(this.scrollHeight);
   }).find( 'textarea' ).change();  
 }
```

And do not forget to call the function on **document ready**:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     change_textarea();
  )};
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is another plug, that also support horizontal growing of text areas:

https://github.com/dgbeck/jquery.autogrow-textarea

It is also based on the "mirror" approach but falls back to simple math in IE 8 and lower, since the mirror approach leads to textareas that grow too quickly in IE <= 8.