# How to Automatically adjust TextArea Height in GWT or Smart GWT

Tags: smartgwt

I'm having a problem that others have talked about here. ie How to auto adjust TextArea Height. I saw this answer: [Creating a textarea with auto-resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize)

but I was hoping someone here can translate how to do this in GWT or Smart GWT.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a link to an auto adjusted text area so that answerers have a better idea of what you are looking for.

Comment: Any news about this? Looking exactly for the same problem

Comment: See this for a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54842360/gwt-resize-textarea-in-ie-internet-explorer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SimpleLayoutPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/index.html?com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SimpleLayoutPanel.html). It enables you to respond to the browser's resize events.

Answer (score 0):

There's a dedicated sample in SmartGWT for this use case:

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#layout_form_filling

If you're using SmartGWT you should not introduce core GWT widgets without a good reason (and there isn't one here obviously).

Comment: This example shows a Canvas auto resizing to fill available space. It doesn't show how to do it with a TextAreaItem