# how to add an auto expand to ace editor

Tags: javascript, jquery

im using the ace editor and im unable to modify it to autoexpand when the user input is longer than the current size:
here is how i have it currently (it has a handler for shift+enter), and it does not work.

```
Typist.prototype.heightUpdateFunction = function() {
          var newHeight =
              ac.getSession().getScreenLength()
              * ac.renderer.lineHeight
              + ac.renderer.scrollBar.getWidth();
           $(settings.id).height(newHeight.toString() + "px");
           ac.resize();
           };

Typist.prototype.createinput = function(settings,handler) {
    var that = this;
    var $typepad = $("<div/>" ,{
          id  : settings.id,
           }).css({position:'relative', height: '40px'}) ;
    $(that.place).append($typepad);
    var ac = ace.edit(settings.id);
    ac.commands.addCommand({
          name : 'catchKeys',
          bindKey : { win : 'Shift-Enter',  mac : 'Shift-Enter' },
          exec : function (ac) {
          if (typeof handler === "function") {
                     handler(ac);
              }
          },
          readOnly : false
          });
    that.heightUpdateFunction();
    ac.getSession().on('change', that.heightUpdateFunction);

    return true;
};
```

how would i get it to work? this current code does not.
How would i access the object that called the height update? (or  the "id" of the div containing the ace editor, since i have several, each with an id reachable by

```
a.inpid
```

given

```
a = new Typist()
```

my attempt comes from reading [this similar kind of problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584061/automatically-adjust-height-to-contents-in-ace-cloud9-editor/13579233#13579233) i dont want to go that way because i will have several  ace editors on the page, and i need to know the id of the one to apply the height adjustment to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out i missed something simple

```
Typist.prototype.heightUpdateFunction = function() {
      var newHeight =
          ac.getSession().getScreenLength()
          * ac.renderer.lineHeight
          + ac.renderer.scrollBar.getWidth();
       $("#"+settings.id).height(newHeight.toString() + "px");  // i forgot $() needs '#'
       ac.resize();
       };
```

my bad. This omission kept me awake for hours. 
EDIT:
see comment in the code to find my correction