# Autoresize is not defined On Jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, autoresize

One year ago, I was looking for about autoresize textarea and I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11628269/1297435), at that time this script works fine in jsfiddle, but now it does not work, I got an error message on console browser looks like :

`Uncaught ReferenceError: autoresize is not defined`

I tried to make it on my computer as `index.html`, and it works.

My question, why is it not working now in jsfiddle?
Sorry, maybe my question is not so important, I'm just curious, is this an error in jsfiddle, or error in script?

```
function autoresize(textarea) {
    textarea.style.height = '24px';
    textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + 12 + 'px';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's that <s>damned</s> useful `onLoad` wrapper:

[image]

Just change it to `No wrap`:

[image]

... and it will work. It didn't work because your `autoresize` function was wrapped in `onLoad` handler, which made not possible to find your function in the scope.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ErWxU/2/

Comment: haha, I did not realize it, thank you for telling me, by default jsffidle function wrapped in onLoad