# Changing element's position (from the top?) to follow 5px after the box above it

Tags: html, css

How do I change an element's `position` so that it adapts to the element above it, so when the box gets bigger (as people enter more text, the box's `{height:auto;}` gets bigger or smaller as more text gets entered) anyway how do I make the second box's `position` go just `5px` (the space between the boxes) past the first box?

Comment: `margin-top:5px`? Can you be more specific?

Comment: You can't do this with CSS alone. You need to use Javascript
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ability to nest the elements? If so you could use relative positioning.  Here is a fiddle, I made the top `<div>` resizable with jQuery UI so you can see the second `<div>` responding to the change in height of the first one:  http://jsfiddle.net/RFaGZ/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="one">
        <div id="two"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#one {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#two {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top:103%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```