# Input field that gets taller as you type

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wonder how I can create a text input that has an auto-adjustable height so that it gets taller to fit your text? For example, if I start typing a paragraph, it expands from a few lines to fit the paragraph.

Here's what I've currently got:

```css
#commenttext {
  width: 413px;
  min-height: 22px;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #777777;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Tahoma";
  top: 7px;
  position: relative;
  left: 7px;
  padding-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="commenttext">
</form>
```

But that's just a normal text area.

How can I make that text area get taller as I type more lines?  Do I need Javascript?

Comment: Use `textarea`. Or you may be able to find some ready-to-use libraries too.

Comment: Agreed, both `input` and `textarea` need javascript to have a height of `auto`

Comment: for comments it's better to use textarea with autogrow. It's already good to be K.I.S.S. We all start being stupid on something that we want to try

Comment: @DrixsonOseña what do you mean

Comment: @ThinkkSo use `textarea`. Saves your time and work, and logically not all web use input tags for comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a CSS-only solution: Use a `div` with `contenteditable` set to true.

```
<div contenteditable="true"
    style="width:200px;min-height:20px;border:1px solid #ccc;"></div>
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/afHm8/) for an example.

**EDIT:**
If you want to be able to submit this text, you'll need a little bit of javascript to put it into an `input` field.  Add this to your form:

```
<form onsubmit="document.getElementById('hidden_data').value=document.getElementById('showing_data').innerHTML;">
    <input id="hidden_data" name="data" type="hidden"/>
    <div id="showing_data" contenteditable="true"
        style="width:200px;min-height:20px;border:1px solid #ccc;"></div>
</form>
```

This will put the contents of the `div` into a hidden `input` field so it will be submitted to the server through `POST` with anything else.

See this (updated) [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/afHm8/2/) for an example.

Comment: There you Go... Mr.Anything is Possible , thanks Alot superscript

Comment: how would i go about if i want it to be a form input or should i put it inside the form elements?

Comment: Nice! I had no idea that was possible.

Comment: if I use this how Would I be Able to insert into mysql?

Comment: VERY nice.  I also had no idea this was possible.

Comment: @ThinkkSo: I made it submittable!  Let me know if you have any more problems.

Comment: @SuperScript I Would Have To Add A Submit Button Right??

Comment: @ThinkkSo: Yes you will -- hitting enter in the `div` will not submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post here:

[Creating a textarea with auto-resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize)

It has all the code needed (HTML and Javascript) to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Okay if i do use this way will i be able to fix the textarea input by myself? because if i can i'd rather not use that

Comment: What do you mean by "fix the text area"?   When you are using textarea, it actually allows you to resize by dragging the box to the size you want.   That happens without any code.    If you want the textarea to increase automatically, you'll need some Javascript :)

Comment: okay yeah like you said dragging the box size, i dont want to be able to do that i want it to be auto lol