# Set a textbox Multiline without losing CSS

Tags: css, textbox, multiline

I have a project with several textboxes and need some of them to become Multiline.
But the problem is, when I set them Multiline I lose all my CSS styles.
I've searched around and found out that textbox turns into TextArea on runtime, is Multiline is selected.
Although, I'm still looking for a way to keep or overwrite somehow the CSS to keep my backcolor, size and preferred font

Comment: Try writing same CSS for textarea.

Comment: Did you checked this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize

Answer (score 7):

I don't really understand what you mean. Multiline Textboxes are Textareas, but thats not set on runtime. You have to expand your css selection and add textarea.

I don't know if that is what you are looking for, but I just made an example on jsfiddle:
[http://jsfiddle.net/N79fj/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/N79fj/1)

HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="test" /><br /> <!-- Textbox -->
    <textarea name="textarea" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea> <!-- Textarea (Multiline) -->
</form>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="text"], textarea {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your CSS so that instead of it applying to `input[type=text]` it applies to `textarea`.

Also change your actual HTML to make the "multiline" textboxes into TextArea's.

I'm also slightly confused what you mean by "runtime". There is no run-time in HTML/CSS web pages?

Comment: This is as asp.net page so that's why i said "runtime"

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.textArea { 
  background: #ccc !important; 
  font-size:12px !important; 
 } /*change css properties as you want*/
```

Apply this class on your multi line textbox with `class="textArea"` attribute.

Comment: you checked that in firebug? see my update in answer. try writing `!important` after every property.

Comment: you checked in firebug..? what it is showing there?

Comment: apparently it's ok. I'm using IE9 and checked with F12, and it is showing the CSS configurations as they should appear on screen... but sadly they aren't