# textarea slow loading times

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm having long loading times when using a lot of textareas.

```
    <?php
    foreach($hold as $value){
      $card_key     = $value['card_key'];
      $card_one     = $value['card_one'];
      $card_two     = $value['card_two'];
      $card_three   = $value['card_three'];
      echo '<li class="row_'.$card_key.'" value="'.$card_key.'">
        <p>'.$i.'.</p>
        <button type="button" value="'.$card_key.'" tabindex="-1"></button>
        <div class="edit_one">
          <textarea class="text1" maxlength="1000">'.$card_one.'</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="edit_two">
          <textarea class="text2" maxlength="1000">'.$card_two.'</textarea>
          <textarea class="text3" maxlength="1000">'.$card_three .'</textarea>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>';
      echo '</li>';
      $i++;
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery.elastic.source.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.edit_main textarea').elastic();
    </script>
```

When $hold contains 1-10 it doesn't take that long to load, but when it has 50 or so it takes 8+ seconds to load.

Is there a faster way to load multiple textareas?
Should I instead use AJAX to load them in one at a time so it appears seamless?

Comment: What defines `$hold`?

Comment: @JayBlanchard It's an associative array. I commented out the textarea boxes, and it ran smooth. So the problem is defintely coming from there.

Comment: Why do you create all those `$card_*****` variables, why do not use directly the `$value` array? It won't solve your problem, just i do not understand.

Comment: @lolka_bolka To keep things a little more organized. Is it problematic?

Comment: No, just really unnecessarey. You are not using them later, you are not manipulating them, so they are just wasting your memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a good answer that might solve your problem.

Take out elastic and replace it with this. Elastic can cause slow loading times in some browsers when there are many textareas.

```
  function textarea_resize(e){
    $(e).css({'height':'auto'}).height(e.scrollHeight);
  }
  $('textarea').each(function(){
    textarea_resize(this);
  }).on('input', function(){
    textarea_resize(this);
  });
```

[Creating a textarea with auto-resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize#25621277#25621277)