# Resize textarea width while typing using keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are two textareas which has the exact same text formatting. IDs are `textareaA` and `textareaB`.

I've set some stuff to happen for textareaA keyup. My question is How do I set a `textareaB` to resize its WIDTH while the user is typing in `textareaA`?

This is what I tried but no luck.

```
$(document).on("click blur keyup", ".fT", function() { // keyup responds with textareaA
        var newWidth = $("#textareaA").val(); //does not work
        $("#textareaB").width(newWidth);
});
```

Comment: There are some great answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize

Comment: @Alexander: thanks, that's about scrollHeight. I'm looking for width.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.css("proprety", "value")` JQuery Method to perform this.

Usage :

```
$(document).keyup(function(event)) {
    $("#textareaB").css("width", "1000px");
});
```

Usage (with variable) :

```
var myVariable = 1000; /* integer here */

$(document).keyup(function(event)) {
    $("#textareaB").css("width", myVariable.toString() + "px");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this has a fixed width?

Comment: I set a fixed width, but you can use a variable instead, but I don't think it can run with integer, you should convert the variable into string first.

Comment: That's similar to my question? Well... how do you suggest I get the value to replace 1000px?

Comment: @Fergoso do this $("#textareaB").css({"width": newWidth+"px"});

Comment: Does not resize its width.

Comment: @Fergoso Can you create a fiddle? And did Zeratops answer not help you?

Comment: @Zeratops: I see you've edited your answer. Where does the `var myVariable = 1000;` come frome? Calculation?

Comment: @Donte'Trumble: No, it's same as your answer.

Comment: I set myself a variable, but we can imagine this variable is modifyied through different process. Like @Donte'Trumble suggests, create a fiddle by editing your question, it will let us know what is happening wrong.

Comment: just created a fiddle and it works http://jsfiddle.net/y80jgnn5/. Focus on the bottom textarea and type. Textarea resizes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#TextAreaId').keyup(function(e) {
         while ($(this).outerHeight() < this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"))) {
             $(this).height($(this).height() + 1);
         };
     });
```

**EDIT 2**: (Increase textarea width)

**note ::change the value '8' in if according to your need and best fit**

```
$(function() {   
$('#mta').keyup(function(e) {

    console.log($(this).outerWidth()+'--'+$(this).val().length*8);
         if($(this).outerWidth() > $(this).val().length) {
             $(this).width($(this).width() + 1);
         };
     });

 });
```

Comment: Thanks. This adjusts the height? I'm looking for a solution which adjust its width.

Comment: My requirement is to set the width of the textarea to the length of its text only. E.g.: if there is a 6 word sentence or a 2 word sentence I would want the textarea to be only to its length of text. I want to avoid any unwanted length of the textarea.