# Make textarea scale vertically to fit text?

Tags: javascript

I have created a textarea that outputs custom text. I want to have it scale to fit the text if there is too much, and not have to scroll (unless the textarea is a certain height). I also do not want to be able to manually scale the textarea. How would I go about doing this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: [HTML <textarea> Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)

Comment: do you also want textarea of fixed width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize).
Seems to be a solution for you problem.
There is a jsfiddle in the accepted answer that shows the result.

To take out the most important function see below. It sets the textareas height equal to its scrollHeight.

```
function resize () {
    var text = document.getElementById('text');
    text.style.height = 'auto';
    text.style.height = text.scrollHeight+'px';
}
```

Comment: it would be better (since you post an answer) to be self-contained and also reference the original answer

Comment: You mean copying the answer from the other thread, so in case it gets deleted/lost the answer is still available?

Comment: well i wouldnt say copy exactly, rather do a creative reformulation ;)

Comment: I have added some information about the function of wich I think its the most important.

Answer (score 0):

You have do this via CSS

```
textarea
{ 
   overflow : auto;
}
```