# Make input element auto-size like a span

Tags: html, css

A `<span>` knows what horizontal size to be without being told. It's horizontal size is no greater than its content.

I'm trying to figure out the CSS to make an `<input type='text'>` automatically size itself horizontally according to the length of its `value`, like a `<span>` would with its `innerText`.

In other words, without specifying a CSS `width:` or `size` attribute on the `<input>`.

I can't figure out how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: that would be one way: http://jsfiddle.net/xm3LL6oq/1/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize

Answer (score 3):

If you want to expand or increase the width of input field as you type you could do something like this

```
<div>
    <span contenteditable="true">sdfsd</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
span{
    border: solid 1px black;
}
div{
    max-width: 200px;   
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9rbb5gpj/)

Or You could accomplish this using some jQuery

```
<input size="1" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input').on('keydown', function(evt) {
    var $this = $(this),
        size = parseInt($this.attr('size'));

    if ( evt.which === 8 ) {
        // backspace
        $this.attr('size', size - 1);
    } else {
        // all other keystrokes
        $this.attr('size', size + 1);
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ob8qb3g/)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the span and input to be the same width no matter what, correct?

If this is the case then this is the way I would go about it:

Wrap both the span and input with a div

then,

```
span, input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

And set your wrapping div to whatever width you want and the two elements should be aligned (automatically, no matter what) and the same width.