# Dynamically expand the height of a textarea when typing more then the max width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I grow the textarea horizontally when typing more then the max width of a text area element? Also I don't want to see the horizontal scrollbar.

rendered html

```html
<textarea name="CatchPhrase" class="input-validation-error" id="CatchPhrase" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="CatchPhrase-error" rows="2" cols="20" data-val-required="The Catch Phrase field is required." data-val="true" data-val-maxlength-max="50"
data-val-maxlength="The field Catch Phrase must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '50'." htmlattributes="{ id = profileCatchPhrase, class = form-control }">I like yoga sd;lasdlk asdks';aksd'asd 'asd';las ';asd'lasd';las'dl as'dla'sdl'asld as'd;las'dl; a;sdlka;sdklasd ;alsd;lkasda ;alskd;lkasd ;lkasd;lk</textarea>
```

Before rendering HTML

```html
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CatchPhrase, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CatchPhrase, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "profileCatchPhrase", @class = "form-control" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CatchPhrase, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$('#CatchPhrase').on('input', function() {
  $(this).outerHeight(38).outerHeight(this.scrollHeight);
});
```

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34513436/4613398

jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/3qmztmjj/

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly & you want to increase the horizontal width of the text area you can check the text characters with maxlength & use steps to increase the width. Hope this snippet is help full for you.

```
$("#profileCatchPhrase").keypress(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > $(this).attr("data-val-maxlength-max")) {
      var width = parseInt($(this).css("width").split("p")[0]) + 10;
      $(this).css("width", width + "px");
      $(this).attr("data-val-maxlength-max", parseInt($(this).attr("data-val-maxlength-max")) + 5);
    }
  });
```

In this i have used 10px as the icreament steps, you can adjust it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

well, i assume u want to expand textarea horizontally not vertically then u Could try something like this:

```
<textarea type="text" value="" placeholder="Autosize"></textarea>
```

and write a simple javascript function which would expand horizontally:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function () {
 // I'm assuming that 1 letter will expand the input by 10 pixels
 var oneLetterWidth = 10;

 // I'm also assuming that input will resize when at least eleven characters
 // are typed
 var minCharacters = 11;
 var len = $(this).val().length;
 if (len > minCharacters) {
     // increase width
     $(this).width(len * oneLetterWidth);
 } else {
     // restore minimal width;
     $(this).width(150);
 }
});
```

This will works perfectly.you can also set the textarea max-width as it should stop expanding after some time so just include this css in head section of your html:

```
 textarea { 
 max-width: 400px;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

use jquery and id of textarea like below

```
$(function() {
   $('#CatchPhrase').autogrow();
});
```

Comment: Yes, here is the [link](https://plugins.jquery.com/autogrow/) for getting autogrow plugin.

Comment: this demo link doesn't autogrow the height. I want something like http://flaviusmatis.github.io/flexibleArea.js/ but without the scrollbar