# How to get correct textarea scrollHeight after Its width has changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the `height` of a `textarea` according to its `scrollheight`.

This works fine the first time i change the `height` however i got to a scenario where it doesn't work for me, I've made jsFiddle to show what i'm doing and what's going wrong.

**Step by step explanation of jsfiddle scenario:**

**1:** Click **`button1`** and check the current `scrollheight`.

**2:** Click **`button3`** and then **`button1`** and notice that the `scrollheight` value has decreased.

**3:** Click **`button2`** and then **`button1`** and notice that the `scrollheight` value is back again.

**You can switch back and forth between `width` 50 and 100 before you continue and check its `scrollheight`, it will change all the time. Now what happens when we continue is what's going wrong for me.**

**4:** Make sure `width` is **50%** by clicking **`button2`** then Click **`button4`** and notice that the `textarea` `height` has increased.

**5:** Click **`button1`** and check its current `scrollheight`.

**6:** Now click **`button3`** to change it's `width` to **100%**

**7:** Click **`button1`** and notice that the `scrollheight` is still the same even tho we just changed its `width` from **50%** to **100%** ??

As you can see here the `scrollheight` is no longer changing, and not the textarea height either, even though i changed the `textarea` `width`, Anyone know why this is happening? Any help or input is highly appreciated, thanks!

```
$("#b1").click(function(){
    var textaraElement =document.getElementById("TextArea");
    alert(textaraElement.scrollHeight);
});
```

[jsFiddleExample](https://jsfiddle.net/r76bv7vq/7/)

Comment: what you expect? `button4` set textarea height explicitly, when content height is less than textarea height, the `scrollHeight` is textarea height plus padding

Comment: Is there anyway to identify the scrollheight after button4 has been pushed? even tho the textarea width changes, just like before button4 has been pushed

Comment: But your logic is wrong because `scrollHeight` cannot be less than the height

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that the height is always the same as the scrollHeight, is this possible? even tho the width of the textarea changes

Comment: You mean textarea should have size of its content?

Comment: @mattias http://stackoverflow.com/a/454409/1414562

Comment: yes @LGSon thanks Wolff I'll look into that one

Comment: That's said, the simple fix would be to set before checking scrollHeight, height explecitely to 0: https://jsfiddle.net/r76bv7vq/8/

Comment: Exactly, was a short and simple fix