# Textarea doesn't make its parent higher

Tags: html, css

When I put multiple lines inside `textarea`, it doesn't make its parent higher, but gains a scrollbar (so not like a typical `div`). I guess this is default behavior but I'd like to have it resize parent instead. Parent has some initial height but should be able to become higher (think multiline chat input).

Code:

```
<div class="parent">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div class="other"></div>
<div>


.parent {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0
  height: auto;
}
textarea {
  min-height: 52px
  height: auto
}
.other {
  height: 52px
}
```

Wrapping `textarea` in another `div` doesn't change anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a textarea with auto-resize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this before by using this jQuery library, unfortunately there's no way doing this in pure CSS.

http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's default behavior for textarea to stay same height.

You can use some plugin like [`autogrow.js`](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/HrnHb/) to increase textarea height (together increasing parent height).

Answer (score 0):

Try this..! Might help

```
<textarea style="overflow:auto"></textarea>
```

Or

```
<textarea style="overflow:hidden"></textarea>
```

Or

```
<textarea style="resize:none"></textarea>
```

Else try this.!

**code.css**

```
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.of_none {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
.of_scrollbar {
  -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
}
```

**code.html**

```
<body>
  <div class="of_none">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
  <div class="of_scrollbar">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `Autosize` of Jacklmoore.

You can find the documentation on the following website: [Autosize by Jacklmoore](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/)

> Usage:

```
// from a jQuery collection
autosize($('textarea'));
```