# Add additonal row to input if text is too long

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-input

### Question

How can i linebreak the input and add an additional "row" if the value text is too long for the current input width (bootstrap responsiveness).

### Current code

```
<input id="someID" type="text" class="form-control" value="some text that is too long for my input width">
```

The value is prefilled by a passed django variable (but that doesn't matter).

### Example

http://www.bootply.com/Y1IFdLMpig

Comment: you realize there are no linebreaks in inputs right? what are you trying to do... maybe you want to use a textarea instead..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a new input field? If that is the case you count the characters passed and add another input field if character count > whatever you define.
If you are looking to make the input field multi-line - my understanding is that you need to use a textarea instead.

```
<textarea>This is where you put the text.</textarea>
```

You can also look at the following if you want it to be auto-resized:
[Creating a textarea with auto-resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize)

Comment: If someone is interested i do now use a `textarea` with `rows=1` and then change the height by `$("textarea").height( $("textarea")[0].scrollHeight );`