# Not able to set minimum height of textarea

Tags: html, css

I want to add textarea of minimum height 27px and as we enter data that should increase its height.

CSS

```
textarea{
  min-height:27px;
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea>Text hello</textarea>
```

Comment: Works for me in mac/chrome.. but i tested with 200px :)

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize

Answer (score 1):

You'd use `div` with `contentEditable` attribute

```css
div {
    display:inline-block;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    min-height: 27px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable="true">    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

already textarea min-height is 80px so 27px is not working. you can use third party plugins.