# React textarea grows but doesn't shrink, how to make it shrink?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, textarea, shrink

I have this React component, which successfully grows the textarea.

```
.textarea {
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


export default function Textarea({
  className,
  onChange,
  defaultValue,
  ...attrs
}) {
  const handleInput = (e) => {
    const h = e.target.scrollHeight
    e.target.style.height = '0px'
    e.target.style.height = `${h}px`
    onChange?.(e)
  }

  return (
    <textarea {...attrs} defaultValue={defaultValue} onInput={handleInput} className={styles.textarea} />
  )
}
```

How do I get it to *shrink* though, it only *grows*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript/react dynamic height textarea (stop at a max)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401504/javascript-react-dynamic-height-textarea-stop-at-a-max)

Comment: For some reason none of these answers are working, hmm...