# How to resize textarea based by content? On start one row

Tags: html, css

I have this textarea:

```
 <textarea class="readonly" type="text" disabled>123456789 - JPP Bla bla bla lba Teest</textarea>
```

So what i want if its small text to have one row (like input), but if i have more text to add rows automatically. I dont want to use jquery, only css and html. Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a textarea with auto-resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize)

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it only by using CSS and HTML, some kind of javascript must be involved...

https://www.impressivewebs.com/textarea-auto-resize/

Comment: this is not one row on start

Comment: Well u can put default height in that case, but if u want to resize, javascript needs to be involved

Comment: do u have example with javascript? but not jquery only javascript because im using anuglar i dont want to mix jquery and angular

Comment: They are really similar, you can adjusted the code in 10 minutes, jquery is initially javacript...