# HTML TextArea autoheight

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a textarea that has no [rows] attribute.
On first, the height should be 35px.

```
----------


Text Here

----------
```

Then, if the user break a new line [Shift + Enter]. the textarea should be like this.

```
------------------

Text Here

Another Line

------------------
```

But, on the next new line. the textarea should be scrollable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a textarea with auto-resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add following code:

```
style: max-height: 35px; overflow: scroll;
```

Comment: Hi Michal,
I already did that. but on first the height should be 35 and should adjustable up to 75px. and then scrollable.

but when you enter Shift+enter 
the height didn't adjust

Answer (score 0):

You can check scrollHeight of your textarea at every [keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event and then set height accordingly.

```
  $('textarea').keyup(function(){
    $(this)[0].style.height = ($(this)[0].scrollHeight)+"px";
});
```

And also you need to set overflow hidden.

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 20px; 
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L54r15L2/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var text    = $(this).val();
            var newline = text.split('\n');
            if(newline.length === 2) {
                $el.removeClass('scroll');
                $el.attr({
                    style : 'height : 60px'
                });
            }
            if(newline.length === 3) {
                $el.removeClass('scroll');
                $el.attr({
                    style : 'height : 75px'
                });
            }
            if(newline.length > 3) {
                $el.addClass('scroll');
            }

            if(newline.length === 0 || newline.length === 1) {
                $el.removeClass('scroll');
                $el.prop('style',false);
            }
```

I don't know if it is a good idea.