# Equivalent of getElementsByTagName in angular

Tags: angular, textarea

I'm trying to select all `textarea` in one web page.

Is there a way to get all these elements in one single query and loop over them to add to each one a listener using the [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) [*`renderer.listen`*](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#listen) in order to implement a [vertical auto expand  of the `textarea`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize) whenever I add text.

if I use @viewchild, I have to add manually a different template reference variable for each of them.

> is it possible to have something similar to getElementsByTagName in angular and avoid direct access to DOM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directives are a perfect case for your scenario.

This isn't the final implementation but should give you a good idea how to use it.

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'textarea[resize]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {

  @HostBinding('style.height.px') 
  height: number;

  @HostListener('change') 
  @HostListener('cut')
  @HostListener('paste')
  @HostListener('drop')
  @HostListener('keydown') 
  onClicked(event: Event) {
    this.resize();
  }

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  resize() {
    const textArea = this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLTextAreaElement;
    this.height = textArea.scrollHeight;
  }
}
```

In your template decorate your `textarea`:

```
<textarea resize></textarea>
```

Comment: I think you are using a direct access to Dom ? but will look at it.

Comment: (revised answer for HostBinding)
`ElementRef` gives you access to the native element in the DOM, in which case you need it because Angular currently [cannot read DOM properties](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18068).

Comment: initially the scrollbar is visible, so I've added `overflow-y:hidden` but now I've to count the initial number of lines inside the `textarea` to set the initial value of number of rows... otherwise there is a number of lines that are hidden.

Comment: This directive looks good, just a small issue when doing enter the first time the upper line in the `textarea`, goes a little bit upper and whenever I remove a line or delete a letter the upper line shows completely inside, don't know why, may be we have to capture mouse down or its other thing ... but I've added `overflow-y: hidden` too, otherwise I keep see the scroll

Comment: It looks like by adding `@HostListener('keyup') onkeyup(event: Event) { this.resize(); }` its a little bit better.

Comment: @HDJEMAI cool! Yeah the implementation I provided basically matched what was requested.