# Dynamic height for text area

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way for me to increase the height of the textarea

```
<textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
```

instead of the scroll feature that we get when the input exceeds the width and height of the field? For example if the user enters 2 paragraphs the entire paragraph should be visible. The textarea should only have 1 or 2 line heights at the beginning when it is empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a textarea with auto-resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below script to achieve that.

```
$("#textarea").on("keyup", function(event){
    if($(event.currentTarget).outerHeight() < $(event.currentTarget)[0].scrollHeight){
    $(event.currentTarget).height($(event.currentTarget)[0].scrollHeight);
  }
});
```

I have created snippet as well.

```js
$("#textarea").on("keyup", function(event){
 if($(event.currentTarget).outerHeight() < $(event.currentTarget)[0].scrollHeight){
   $(event.currentTarget).height($(event.currentTarget)[0].scrollHeight);
  }
})
```

```css
#textarea{
  height:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control" id="textarea"></textarea>
```

You can also test it here.. https://jsfiddle.net/zrnp7gkm/8/

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!