# How to make <textarea> take the size of text

Tags: html

how can I make a  tag take the size of the text inside?

I mean how can I make it that even if the text is to long it will show the full text and not the scroll bar?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a textarea with auto-resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James Padolsey has a super nice jQuery script for [auto resizing textareas](https://j11y.io/demos/plugins/jQuery/autoresize.jquery.js) (That's gone off and on the internet, so here's a backup.)

```
/*
 * jQuery autoResize (textarea auto-resizer)
 * @copyright James Padolsey http://james.padolsey.com
 * @version 1.04
 */

(function($){

    $.fn.autoResize = function(options) {

        // Just some abstracted details,
        // to make plugin users happy:
        var settings = $.extend({
            onResize : function(){},
            animate : true,
            animateDuration : 150,
            animateCallback : function(){},
            extraSpace : 20,
            limit: 1000
        }, options);

        // Only textarea's auto-resize:
        this.filter('textarea').each(function(){

                // Get rid of scrollbars and disable WebKit resizing:
            var textarea = $(this).css({resize:'none','overflow-y':'hidden'}),

                // Cache original height, for use later:
                origHeight = textarea.height(),

                // Need clone of textarea, hidden off screen:
                clone = (function(){

                    // Properties which may effect space taken up by chracters:
                    var props = ['height','width','lineHeight','textDecoration','letterSpacing'],
                        propOb = {};

                    // Create object of styles to apply:
                    $.each(props, function(i, prop){
                        propOb[prop] = textarea.css(prop);
                    });

                    // Clone the actual textarea removing unique properties
                    // and insert before original textarea:
                    return textarea.clone().removeAttr('id').removeAttr('name').css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: 0,
                        left: -9999
                    }).css(propOb).attr('tabIndex','-1').insertBefore(textarea);

                })(),
                lastScrollTop = null,
                updateSize = function() {

                    // Prepare the clone:
                    clone.height(0).val($(this).val()).scrollTop(10000);

                    // Find the height of text:
                    var scrollTop = Math.max(clone.scrollTop(), origHeight) + settings.extraSpace,
                        toChange = $(this).add(clone);

                    // Don't do anything if scrollTip hasen't changed:
                    if (lastScrollTop === scrollTop) { return; }
                    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;

                    // Check for limit:
                    if ( scrollTop >= settings.limit ) {
                        $(this).css('overflow-y','');
                        return;
                    }
                    // Fire off callback:
                    settings.onResize.call(this);

                    // Either animate or directly apply height:
                    settings.animate && textarea.css('display') === 'block' ?
                        toChange.stop().animate({height:scrollTop}, settings.animateDuration, settings.animateCallback)
                        : toChange.height(scrollTop);
                };

            // Bind namespaced handlers to appropriate events:
            textarea
                .unbind('.dynSiz')
                .bind('keyup.dynSiz', updateSize)
                .bind('keydown.dynSiz', updateSize)
                .bind('change.dynSiz', updateSize);

        });

        // Chain:
        return this;

    };



})(jQuery);
```

[Here's another by Louis Lazeris](https://www.impressivewebs.com/textarea-auto-resize/), which also includes links to other options. It works just how you likely hope it does. The textarea starts out a normal reasonable size. As you type more and more content, the textarea expands to include all of that text, rather than triggering a scrollbar as is the default.

The plugin has a variety of options, but at its simplest you just load jQuery, the plugin file, and call it like this:

```
$('textarea').autoResize();
```

Another trick here is to not use a  at all, but . That will grow automatically with no fancy JavaScript help at all - except that it's not a real form element anymore so you'll need JavaScript to extract/send the value.

Source - https://css-tricks.com/textarea-tricks/

Comment: Thanks, will look into this

Comment: James Padolsey's plugin works fine but it only triggers when I click on text area and press a button any way to make it automatic?

Comment: adding  $("textarea").trigger("change.dynSiz"); after autoresize() solved my issue there for I'm going to make this the accepted answer, thanks

Comment: Because of the clone, this method leaves you with two textareas in the source code so does anyone know the best way to make this accessible?