# Auto resize not wokring on textareas on different tabs

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor

I am building a razor page and are using different tabs with autoresizing textares.
I have followed the solution listed as Option 2 on this link:
[Creating a textarea with auto-resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize/25621277?noredirect=1#comment125812767_25621277)
And it looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const tx = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
for (let i = 0; i < tx.length; i++) {
  tx[i].setAttribute("style", "height:" + (tx[i].scrollHeight) + "px;overflow-y:hidden;");
  tx[i].addEventListener("input", OnInput, false);
}

function OnInput() {
  this.style.height = "auto";
  this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px";
}
</script>
```

This solution only resizes the visible text areas. If I have one textarea on another tab in the same view the text area wont resize until I have typed something in the text area.

It is suggested to use:

```
$("textarea").trigger("input");
```

But I can't get it to do anything.

Here are the clibkable tabs:

```
<ul id="viewTabs" class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-left:5px;">
    @*Create tabs*@
    @foreach (var tab in tabs)
    {
        <li class ="TabClickable" @(tab.Index == 1 ? "class=active" : "")>
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab@(tab.Index.ToString())">
                <span class="tabtitle">
                    @Html.Raw(tab.Name)
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

And the code generating a textarea looks like this.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Field.InstCustomFieldValues.Where(icfv => icfv.InstrumentId == Model.Instrument.Id).FirstOrDefault().String_Value, 1, 40, new { id = Model.Field.FieldName, Name = Model.Field.FieldName, @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Can you share your html with tabs?

Comment: @YiyiYou ofcourse! =)

Comment: Can your share your js function about tabs and code of `#tab@(tab.Index.ToString())`?

Comment: It just changes the active tab to tab.Index. Might be a bootstrap thing, can't find anythign about it in the code. @YiyiYou

Comment: I just realised the `$("textarea").trigger("input");` is jQuery. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @DreamTeK added  <script type="text/javascript"> to question. Javascript.

Comment: I have code like this "$('#catPopup').modal('hide');" that looks very jquery. Is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

**The issue**

All textareas that are not visible on the page will have a default height of 0. When you switch tabs and the textarea becomes visible the height is still 0.

**The fix**

You need to reapply the textarea resizing to the textarea **AFTER** it is made visible.

I recommend you do this in one of two ways:

**1. Reinitialise the entire function when you click the element that makes the textarea visible.**

*(Please note I haven't tested this code. It's off the top of my head.)*

## Pure Javascript

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  resizeTx();
});

function resizeTx() {
  const tx = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");

  for (let i = 0; i < tx.length; i++) {
    tx[i].setAttribute("style", "height:" + (tx[i].scrollHeight) + "px;overflow-y:hidden;");
    tx[i].addEventListener("input", OnInput, false);
  }
}

function OnInput() {
  this.style.height = "auto";
  this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px";
}

const tab = document.getElementsByClassName("TabClickable > a");

for (let i = 0; i < tx.length; i++) {
  tab[i].addEventListener("click", resizeTx, false);
}
```

**2. Trigger the input of the now visible textarea.**

```
const tab = document.getElementsByClassName("TabClickable > a");

for (let i = 0; i < tx.length; i++) {
  tab[i].addEventListener("click", goTextarea, false);
}

function goTextarea() {
  tx.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
}
```

---

## JQuery

You should note it is a lot easier to do this in jQuery as the linked answer suggests.

```
$(".TabClickable > a").on("click", function(){
  $("textarea").trigger("input");
});
```

Comment: is it possible to add jquery to my page? I am trying the pure javascript, thanks alot

Comment: Like you said looks like you are already using it. However if not just add the script to your page root. Be sure it loads before you run any other jquery code.

Comment: Just to be sure, how would I add this code. Can I add it into any <script> section or do I have to do something special with that script section? Is jquery any different from javascript men adding it? maybe the script type="jquery" or something