# ReactJS: Textbox Creating Extra Scroll at Bottom of Page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a React app where I use a textarea to allow users to input text. I want the textarea to fill the height of the screen, but not make the page scrollable unless there's more text than can fit on the screen.

Here is my CSS code (the textarea is entry-input):

```
* {
  margin: auto;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif !important;
  color: #222222;
  background-color: #FAF3E0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-weight: 800 !important;
  color: #111111;
}

.journal-page {
  padding: 4rem 22%;
}

.date-title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
}

.entry-input {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  height: calc(100vh - 5rem);
  background-color: white;
}
```

Removed padding and margins.
Used height: auto in CSS.
Tried JavaScript to dynamically adjust the height based on the content.
Used overflow: hidden and overflow-y: auto.
Inspected and nothing unusual too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[how to dinamically resize a textarea in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73486986/how-to-dinamically-resize-a-textarea-in-react)

I hope this will help you to fix your problem.

Comment: When I do max-height, the textbox is only two lines long even though I have a few paragraphs. Overflow: auto doesn't change anything. =((

Comment: Also, if I resize the window, the issue is gone. It only happens on full desktop. I tried different browsers too.

Comment: I've changed my answer, please take a look at it.