# Textarea height and rows doesn't fit to content in FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I want to implement a textarea which has a dynamic height, so when user add new row then the textarea adapts its height to the new content. The resize property is set to none, and overflow: hidden. I have checked the behavior in chrome and works as expected but in firefox mysteriously doesn't work, the height stays static. Can someone helps me ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a textarea with auto-resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize)

Answer (score -1):

Try changing display: `inline-table;` to `display: inline-block;`