# How do i resize a textarea, to content width, having min-width and max-width?

Tags: html, jquery, css

So, i have troubles with a textarea now, and i cant make it resize to a content width...
Ive found a long and detailed answer about content height, and it works !! but not having the content width on it...

This is that post: [Creating a textarea with auto-resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize)

BUT, my issue isnt solved, i need the width to resize too. Considering max and min widths.

This is the example code:

```js
$("textarea").each(function () {
  this.setAttribute("style", "height:" + (this.scrollHeight) + "px;");
}).on("input", function () {
  this.style.height = 0;
  this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px";
});
$("textarea").trigger("input");
```

```css
textarea{
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
<textarea>this is my normal content, and it has to consider this content to be as long as the max-width</textarea>
<textarea>this is my normal content, should be consider</textarea>
<textarea>this is my min content</textarea>
```

Also, this is how i want them to be:

[image]

Comment: From experience, I would very much recommend you use `<div contenteditable></div>`, AFAIK there's no solution without javascript involved, but I could be wrong

Comment: EDIT: there's no solution without A LOT* of javascript involved

Comment: @savageGoat We where using a div, but they wanted a textarea... idk why.

Comment: Oh wait, i remember now, i need a textarea, because the div doesnt respect the lines... so if i write 2 lines, it doesnt show them on the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

**Note:** as said in the comment, this technique uses the `contenteditable` property instead

```css
#myInput {
  min-height: 20px;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 80%;
  min-width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px;
  resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable id="myInput"></div>
```

Comment: As i said before, this resolves the issue, but not the textarea one... i need a textarea, so i can make more lines, and they stay there.

Comment: @excorpion you mean `[CSS] white-space: pre-line;` ?

Comment: Yeah, now i need to investigate how to save it with break lines, thanks

Comment: You either accept `\n` or translate `<br> -> \n` or the other way around. It's standard practice to store the `\n` (to avoid html tags, and by extensions risks of injections) and either display it with `pre-line` or plain html by replacing them with `<br/>`

Comment: How can i make that replace with jquery ?

Comment: @excorpion first replace `<br>`, something like `element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/\<br\/?\>/g, "\n")`, then get the `textContent`, I belive it's `$(elemnt).text()` in jQuery?

Comment: If you mean to display the text, `text.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>")` for html, and use CSS with plain `\n`