# Autosize textarea using prototype?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on an internal sales application for the company I work for, and I've got a form that allows the user to change the delivery address.

Now I think it would look much nicer, if the **textarea** I'm using for the main address details would just take up the area of the text in it, and automatically **resize** if the text was changed.

[image]

**Any ideas? Gracious !!!**

**Edit by XeeMez**:I've modified the code a little because it was acting a little odd, I changed it to activate on keyup, because it wouldn't take into consideration the character that was just typed.

```
resizeIt = function( ) {
  var str = $( 'iso_address' ).value;
  var cols = $( 'iso_address' ).cols;
  var linecount = 0;
  $A( str.split( "\n" ) ).each( function( l ) {
    linecount += 1 + Math.floor( l.length / cols ); // take into account long lines
  } )
  $( 'iso_address' ).rows = linecount;
};
```

Comment: FYI: probably duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511128/prototype-plugin-for-dynamically-expanding-textarea

Comment: Do you use jQuery? You can maybe bind on the 'change' event from your textarea, and change size everytime the value of it changes.

Comment: Is there a JQuery verion? How to access cols and rows of a TextArea in JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's technique for autosizing a textarea.

```
Uses pixel height instead of line height: more accurate handling of line wrap if a proportional font is used.
Accepts either ID or element as input
Accepts an optional max height param - useful if you'd rather not let the text area grow beyond a certain size (keep it all on-screen, avoid breaking layout, etc.)
Tested on Firefox 3 and IE6
```

Code: **(plain vanilla Javascript)**

```
function FitToContent(id, maxHeight)
{
   var text = id && id.style ? id : document.getElementById(id);
   if ( !text )
      return;

   /* Accounts for rows being deleted, pixel value may need adjusting */
   if (text.clientHeight == text.scrollHeight) {
      text.style.height = "30px";
   }       

   var adjustedHeight = text.clientHeight;
   if ( !maxHeight || maxHeight > adjustedHeight )
   {
      adjustedHeight = Math.max(text.scrollHeight, adjustedHeight);
      if ( maxHeight )
         adjustedHeight = Math.min(maxHeight, adjustedHeight);
      if ( adjustedHeight > text.clientHeight )
         text.style.height = adjustedHeight + "px";
   }
}
```

Demo: (uses jQuery, targets on the textarea i'm typing into right now - if you have Firebug installed, paste both samples into the console and test on this page)

```
$("#post-text").keyup(function() 
{
  FitToContent(this, document.documentElement.clientHeight)
});
```

Comment: @priya that probably wouldn't be too hard to implement, just add another conditional

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach I used.
Call expandTextArea on keyup or keypress.

```
var minimumTextAreaRows = 10;
function expandTextArea(event) {
    var element = event.target;
    element.rows = minimumTextAreaRows;
    while (element.clientHeight < element.scrollHeight) {
        element.rows = element.rows + 1;
    }
};
```

Combine with a css that prevents the scrollbar to avoid it flashing

```
textarea.noscrollbar {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will also "shrink" to the minimum size you specify. Remove `element.rows = minimumTextAreaRows;` to make it not shrink.