# height of textarea increases when value increased but does not reduce when value is decreased

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">$(function(){
$("textarea").live("keyup keydown",function(){var h=$(this);
h.height(h[0].scrollHeight);
});});

</script>
<textarea style="resize:none;width:760px;height:60px; overflow:hidden;" ></textarea>
</body>
```

When textarea get overflowed it get scrollbar and scrollheight which gets applied to its height but not working for decreasing textarea height as on decreasing its value length it doesnot get scrollbar

Comment: what is this script trying to accomplish?

Comment: the title should say it all ... @jbabey

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The minimum scrollHeight of a textarea is always going to be the height. To get an accurate scrollHeight, set the height to 1 first.

```
h.height(1).height(h[0].scrollHeight);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aarongloege/t2vAr/

Comment: god damn you made my answer look silly :) good answer, btw you should put the js fiddle example on your answer so incase that url expires in the future.

Comment: Good work , you can set height at first with any value doesn't matter

Comment: Man, you saved my life! Been the whole day trying to solve this issue.

Comment: Needs to be adjusted since .live is deprecated but it does in fact work when you just make it .on instead. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is this JQuery? What would a pure javascript solution look like?

Comment: @Labrador I added an answer to this page with the code you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Pure JavaScript version of the above code

```
textarea.style.height = '0';
textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to code it by yourself, you can also use this script: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-expandable
It already contains a nice slide-effect ;-)