# ion-textarea resize height dynamically in Ionic 5

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic5, elementref

I am migrating my project from Ionc3 to Ionic5. I have an ion-textarea which increases the height as user types and it works in Ionic3. Following is the code.

HTML page:

```
<ion-textarea #hvUserPost type="text" (input)="adjustDesc()"></ion-textarea>
```

TS page:

```
@ViewChild('hvUserPost') hvUserPost: ElementRef;
adjustDesc() {
    let textArea;
    textArea = this.hvUserPost['_elementRef'].nativeElement.getElementsByClassName("text-input")[0];
    textArea.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    textArea.style.height = 'auto';
    var scrollHeight = textArea.scrollHeight;
    textArea.style.height = scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

Now in Ionic4 the only thing changes is in the following declaration

```
@ViewChild('hvUserPost', {static: false}) hvUserPost: ElementRef;
```

In Ionic4, I am getting the following error.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

So `this.hvUserPost['_elementRef']` is undefined and `this.hvUserPost.nativeElement` is also undefined.

Comment: Add autoGrow="true" attribute in ion-textarea and it will auto inrease,

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. Please put your comments in the Answer so that I can make it the correct answer.

Comment: Your welcime mate <3. I did add it as answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add autoGrow="true" atteibute and it will be done.

```
<ion-textarea #hvUserPost type="text"autoGrow="true" (input)="adjustDesc()"></ion-textarea>
```