# Sizing textarea height according to content with baseline same as input tags within an html table

Tags: html, css, input, textarea

I have inline forms that are displayed as rows in an html table. Each input in those form is an input tag, however a few longer ones use textareas. So that looks like something like this (top one being a textarea, bottom being an input).

[image]

In that case it looks fine, however a lot of the description may be empty, or have only a few words. However the textarea doesn't adjust to the (initial) content:

[image]

I *don't* need this do automatically resize along with use input. However I do need it to have, initially, the ~same height as the input tags when possible. Such as:

[image]

sample html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered dbase-table" id="bottom_product_form" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <caption style="caption-side:top">Products</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="narrow">Product</th>
            <th class="wider">Description</th>
            <th class="narrow">Order</th>
            <th class="narrow">BO</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="details_form">
        <tr>
            <td class="">
                <input type="text" name="details-0-no_prod" value="7164" maxlength="30" readonly="True" class="readonly" id="id_details-0-no_prod">
            </td>
            <td  class="td_fit">
                <textarea class="input-fit" type="text" name="details-0-tmp_desc" maxlength="60" id="id_details-0-tmp_desc">this is fine</textarea>
            </td>
            <td  class="">
                <input type="number" name="details-0-qte_cmd" value="1" id="id_details-0-qte_cmd">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="details-0-qte_bo" value="0" readonly="True" class="readonly" id="id_details-0-qte_bo">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With the code below, sure I can set the height of the text-are to be ~ that of the input. However if there's more input in the table, height stays the same and it ends up hidden.

css:

```
table {
  background-color: gray;
}
textarea {
/*    line-height:0.3rem; */
  height:1rem;
  max-height:3rem;
}
```

Comment: Is it same you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477/how-to-autosize-a-textarea-using-prototype      or      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803880/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-textarea-to-stretch-to-fit-its-content-without-using-php

Comment: Not really. I mean sure I could use a js solution as the 1st one. But that's way overkill - I don't want to automatically resize on input. I just want it to size according to its initial content. much like 98% of html element do. The one-line a solution in the 2nd one is not bad, but then initial size is wrong (e.g. needs some user edit before properly resizing).

Maybe somehow one needs to use JS to do that, however for a relative frontend newb, it seems astounding that there wouldn't be some html/css way to do this.